# UK General visitor visa refusal!

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, sudanese-citizens

I've submitted an application to visit my unmarried partner in the UK during Christmas and the Embassy turned it down. My partner is British and I have Sudanese passport.

Entery clearance officer turned down my application because I don't have previous travel history to the UK or any other country with similar immigration system and cash deposit I have made before submitting my application. Regarding the money that he commented on it was a commission that received from work and I didn't submit any evidence where this money came from according to the entry clearance officer.

Can I re-apply for entry clearance again anytime soon? And how to avoid the refusal next time?

Comment: Repeating the question you asked five days ago won't make it easier to answer it.

Comment: Same comment as last time. The reasons you are posting here do not form any part of the immigration rules and do not make sense. You'll get a much more informed answer if you can post the EXACT text of your refusal notification. You can omit their standard boiler plate about about  discrimination.  Flagging this as duplicate

Comment: Since the linked duplicate got deleted, I'm going to remove the duplication mark here.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException is it deleted?  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal seems there, no?

Comment: @MarkMayo Actually [this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38580/general-visitor-visa-refusal) was the older duplicate (now deleted).