# What documents do I need to provide for a UK Visitor Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm preparing a new application to visit my partner in the UK this Christmas.

1. What kind of documents which I should support my application with?
2. I'm resident in Saudi Arabia, but own a Flat in Egypt. Shall I support my application with a translated copy of the flat's contract? Previously, I've noticed a question regarding if I own a property.
3. In the "income and Expenditure" section on the application form, how should I demonstrate My income, savings, monthly living costs as I don't have separated bank account for the savings nor I receive an income from my flat in Egypt and all my income ( salary, commission/ bonus, savings ) fall in one account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question about what documents to provide supporting your application, the "official" reference point is [Visitor: supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf). This guidance tells you what they expect to see and just as importantly, what they do not want to see.

If you study the guidance and see that you have an evidential shortfall, you can usually use your best judgement as to what can be substituted and still maintain the overall quality of evidence.

For your question about how to demonstrate that you own property, you would put the deeds or mortgage statements to demonstrate ownership.

You receive all your income into a single account. It's messy, but can be approached rationally in a way they will find acceptable.  Get 3 - 6 months of statements together and make an accompanying spreadsheet to annotate the provenance for each of the flows in your account. About 85% of the UK refusals we see on this site are sourced in provenance of funds.

You need to take additional care that every deposit into your account is traceable to a legal source.  This is also a big problem for applicants who get refused.

Finally, because you are working out of a single account (probably out of your pocket), you should include a series of tax returns for KSA and Egypt. If you do not have them, expect problems because they may think that if you evade taxes then you are more risky than otherwise.  File retrospective returns if it makes sense to do so.

You didn't ask, but you mentioned that your premise is to visit your partner. Include something that shows there is a substantive relationship that is on-going and likely to last through the course of your visit.

For background info, see [proof-provenance-of-funds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-provenance-of-funds)

Adding: the answer you got for your [previous refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking) still applies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please note that my income in Saudi Arabia is "tax free".

Answer (score 0):

For your flat in Egypt, you can submit a property ownership document.
For your income,it is allright that you have only one account. Take bank statement for 6 months, where it is clearly visible the inflow of your salary.
In addition, submit a contract letter you received from employer on the commencement of your job, along with a salary slip for the last three months. This would be sufficient to clarify your income, its consistency and expenditure.
Also, submit any apartment contract that you currently have where you live.