# UK Visa rejected twice. Whom can I complain to?

Tags: visa-refusals

Please advice-is there an office to which a Visitor Visa Rejection complaint can be sent to?
It's for a UK Visitor Visa rejection.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration/about/complaints-procedure

Comment: TL;DR: Most refusals of UK visitor visas are not appealable. In particularly egregious cases such as when your application has obviously been mixed up with someone else's or numbers in your application are misquoted (to substantive effect) in the decision, you can ask them to double check that it was decided correctly.

Comment: @Vinu Mendis On what basis were you refused and what exactly is the basis of your complaint? If you simply disagree with the decision a complaint will serve for nothing unless the ECO’s made material errors in reaching the decisions.

Comment: What do you expect to achieve with the complaint? Do you just want to complain about the process, or do you want to dispute the outcome itself? Because in the latter case it would not be a _complaint_ but an _appeal_. (If you indeed want to appeal instead of complain, please update your question accordingly)

Answer (score 15):

Should you wish to lodge a formal complaint, the appropriate government department is the Home Office at 2 Marsham Street, London, SW1P 4DF. Its response would likely be a form letter from the correspondence unit advising you to make a fresh application.

Before doing so, please understand that permission to enter the UK, or any country, is not a right or entitlement for those who are not its citizens. After two unsuccessful applications, the best course of action would be to address any issues or shortcomings noted in the refusal letter(s).

Without seeing the actual notices, and the section(s) to which the refusals were cited, here are several comprehensive Q&A's that might be helpful:

[UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

[Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

[What documents do I need to provide for a UK Visitor Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54305/what-documents-do-i-need-to-provide-for-a-uk-visitor-visa/54311#54311)

And, as @Traveller suggests:

[I have been denied a visa several times in a row. How does one deal with such serial refusals?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99216/i-have-been-denied-a-visa-several-times-in-a-row-how-does-one-deal-with-such-se)

Comment: This may also be useful reading https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99216/i-have-been-denied-a-visa-several-times-in-a-row-how-does-one-deal-with-such-se