# UK student visitor refused, what to do next?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, study, proof-provenance-of-funds, standard-visitor-visas

I am 21, Vietnamese and have been accepted for the 26-week-long General English course in St Giles International, Brighton, UK. I have applied to the UK Visas and Immigration office in Vietnam. I have asked for short term student visitor visa and got refused. Now I am reapplying.

Exact wording of the refusal letter quoted here:

> I have refused your application for a  visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph A57 of Appendix V: Immigration rules for Visitor because:
>
> - You have said that you will travel to the UK for a period of 26 weeks, to study a general English course. You have said that upon completion of the course you will return to Vietnam looking for a better job. You appear to have completed your full time studies in Vietnam in 2013, and you have been working in administration role since May 2014. You have not sought to continue your studies in your home country since 2013. and you have not undertaken any English course previously, outside of your high school studies. You are employed and receive a monthly income of VND 5,000,000 (GBP 144.70). Of your GBP 144.70 income you spent GBP 100 on living costs. You have said that your study in the UK will cost you GBP 16,000. Therefore I am unclear why you would elected to travel; to the UK now, at the course involved - when courses are available in Vietnam, considerably cheaper.
> - As evidence of funds available for your trip you have presented a Sacombank savings book, on 14/08/2015 you credited VND 800,000,000 to this account, this is equal to GBP 23,151, and equates to over 13 years total income, before considering your living costs. As such, I am not satisfied of the origin of these funds, or if they are genuinely available to support your visit now. In light of the above, noting the costs involved, in fact you have not sought to study English previously, and there is no evidence that completion of this course would offer you better employment in Vietnam. Coupled the fact that I am not satisfied that the funds a genuinely available to support you visit means I am not satisfied that you intend to leave the UK at the end of the study. Furthermore, I am not satisfied you have enough funds to support your return journey, or that you will be maintained and adequately accommodated out of funds available to you.

First of all, after completing high school, I was not able to make it to a college or university. I got the job as a arrangement of my father with his friend's company. I could live quite easily without the salary thanks to my parents' financial support. In another word, all I needed was just a so called job, no matter how much it would pay me. After a year of being bored of the jobs as well as family dependence, with my parents' encouragement, I decided to go to study abroad to improve my knowledge and experience. I simply think that if I continue being in my country, no matter how much I want to do it, my family will give me everything I need when I am in trouble. And more than to become independent, I want to get a job with my very own sources when I return. I think the course will afford me that.

The funds for my course, obviously, came from my parent. And if the UK Immigration officers have doubt about my return or my bond to my hometown which can assure my return (such as a high salary job or real estate ownership) I just don't know what to show to convince them.

At the moment, all I think of to add to my reapplication are my parents' income statements (though I am not quite sure if it will help because legally, I have been no longer their dependant). Just so you know, I've already had my bank statement, employment description, return ticket booking, study record etc. I desperately want this, and even much more after the refusal, as I don't want to be called parasite any more.

What should I prepare and do to reapply?

I'm so afraid of being refused again and that would be the end of all of this because every time of being refused, it's only getting harder and harder to apply next time.

Comment: YOu'd also need some signed documentation from your parents saying they are willing to support you, on the finance end. I'm not suure what you could even do to convince them you intend to return however - although an interest in study of the subject area, and a history of travel and return might help/

Comment: The 2nd one is always a red flag. Such big transfers just before an application is always going to have a rejection.

Comment: "The funds for my course, obviously, came from my parent.". But your question reads like you tried to make it look as if the funds were yours.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you correctly transcribed your refusal notice...

**I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph A57 of Appendix V: Immigration rules for Visitor because:**

When a refusal notice cites the wrong rule, or a non-existing rule, you can send it back to the issuing post with a brief complaint stating something to the effect of

> "...Appendix V of the Immigration Rules does not contain a Paragraph
>   A57.  Paragraph A57 might be referring to Paragraph A57A of Part 3 of
>   the Immigration Rules but I am unable to be certain of your meaning.
>   Because of this I am unable to understand the grounds for my refusal. 
>   Would you please handle this as a complaint..."

They will not reverse their decision, but if they agree with you (and they will agree given that there's no such rule), you might be awarded a gratis application the next time you apply.  They will also send you a revised notice which cites the correct grounds for their refusal and this will enable you to apply more effectively the next time.

Also, since they obviously wanted to get you on a parking strategy, you should read this before making your next application: [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking/39158#39158)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've just thought of adding some evidences of my fund's origin, like contract of selling real estate (in 2013) -> my father's bank statement -> bank transfer receipt from my father's account to mine (14/8/2015). Do you think it will work?

Comment: @yanchi, the format of this site discourages raising new stuff in comments and turning it into a discussion. If you have a new question, you can ask it, but this answer has to stand 'as is'.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers we don't need 'thanks'