# Can I transfer some money into my bank account before applying for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm going to apply for a visit visa with 2 of my dependants. I'm wondering if I can use my UK bank statement which has been idle for couple of years. Currently, I'm living in Pakistan since I completed my education back in 2013. I'm wondering If I transfer some amount in that account before applying for a Visit visa. This is important to add here that my bank account is active but no transaction has made since September 2013!

Comment: It's a sword that can cut both ways.  Also, make sure they do not suspect funds parking and you will have to supplement it with  your day-to-day living bank account.

Comment: Thanks Fow, is there any issue if my bank account is still open there! I believe I haven't used it for long time. It will be much helpful if you elaborate a bit about "they do not suspect funds parking and you will have to supplement it with your day-to-day living bank account".

Thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: `funds parking` Transfer money into an account just before an application to show you have money. `day-to-day living bank account` Account which you use for your day to day needs and in your country of residence.

Comment: @DumbCoder props to you for the definitions.  I'm not sure this question warrants a formal answer, but please take a shot! I will u/v it for sure :)

Comment: @GayotFow I don't think I can for surety say what the ECO will make of using a bank account in the country to show for subsistence proof. You have more bandwidth on these tricky legalities.

Comment: Also see: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications

Comment: @GayotFow the idea that one would use a bank account *daily* or even monthly is a pretty weird in some locales. What's next, driving a *car* every day? I assume Pakistan might be one of these.

Answer (score 2):

The visa officials want to see two things:

- Can the visitors pay for the their travel and living expenses?
- Can the visitors *reasonably* afford to spend that much money on travel, or does it look like a major investment into an illegal immigration attempt?

The first question requires a certain amount of money. The second question requires a steady income which leaves enough after typical cost-of-living expenses to save for a trip.

Using that old account means you can't show steady deposits of your salary. That will be difficult or impossible to explain.