# How to apply for a Schengen visa for France when paid in cash (income not deposited on a bank account)?

Tags: visas, schengen

I work for a diplomat based in Vietnam. I get paid in cash and banks do not accept personal deposits from foreigners. I want to apply for a Schengen visa but I don't have bank statements however, i can provide pay slips from my boss. Do i need a confirmation letter to support the pay slips? Since I'm paid in cash, do i have to prove that I have the money needed to support my travel for the last 3 months?

Comment: I suppose you don't have a contract, is that why you want to submit a letter of support?

Comment: How/where do you keep your cash? If you send it to your home, do you have exchange receipts?

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications for a related discussion.

Comment: I have a year contract with the family and it states I am paid in cash. The job is funded by the state government. However, in Vietnam transferring money overseas are not allowed so I am keeping some of it and the rest is deposited in my local bank account here. I don't own any credit cards back home.

Answer (score 4):

You need to show both that you are not likely to stay in the Schengen area illegally (i.e. that you have a stable situation in your country of residence) *and* have enough money to cover your trip (that's travel to the Schengen area and back *plus* the costs of your stay, two separate requirements).

Bank statements help with all three requirements and showing you have a stable income over a period of several months (not just cash in hand) is especially useful with respect to the first requirement. Being paid in cash does not really change that, it just makes it harder to document your situation (and being paid in cash and spending it without ever depositing it on an account makes it harder still). Pay slips are good too but any additional evidence can be useful.

Incidentally, do you have a bank account/credit card in another country? Euro banknotes? You also need to be able to spend your cash for your application to be credible.

Comment: I have a contract until 2017 so that would give me a reason to come back. I get pay slips every month but it isn't under a company but only a personal receipt created by my employer. My salary is funded by the state government but the money is not directly transferred to my account.  Do I need to maintain a specific amount every month to be eligible for a visa?What do I need to provide to prove the money is eligible?

Comment: @Raine I think a contract, pay slip and/or letter from your employer is already quite good. There are no guidelines regarding your income but the costs of your trip should be commensurate with your means. If you plan (or claim to plan) to spend your yearly income on a trip to Europe, the consulate will not believe you.