# Visitor visa previously refused due to lack of funds and ties to home country. What's the best strategy for reapplying?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I applied for a visitor visa to the UK in May, which got declined due to insufficient funds and immigration thinking I would not exit the country (I am visiting my BF).

This time, I'm reapplying for a tourist standard visa to the 
UK in August.

I have booked round trip tickets and I have hotel booking confirmation, but haven't paid it yet as it is reserved. I need advice on whether I should consult with a visa immigration consultant for proper visa application procedure.

I have a permanent job and I'm thinking of applying for a personal loan to show them I have sufficient money in my bank account.

Comment: Applying for a loan isn't going to help. Then they'll just want to know where you got the money, they'll see it's from a loan you took out to pad your bank account, and you'll be in even worse shape. They want to see actual assets in your account, not just the fact that you're holding on to somebody else's money for a bit. Please read [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105)

Comment: Ok then taking loan is bad idea ... I do have almost 1500 pounds in my bank account now . Will that sufficient for daily expense for UK for ten days and hotel stay cuz it's price is 417 pounds

Comment: I m going to apply the visa in July end or Aug end when I get my salary . Is it better to go with immigration consultant

Comment: The danger is that there are a lot of unqualified and/or unscrupulous consultants who will try to take advantage of you. Some will take your money and give you nothing in return. Some may encourage you to submit an application with false documents and get you banned from the UK. Be extremely cautious. Fundamentally, the officer reviewing your application is going to be concerned that you are spending a huge chunk of your savings on a trip to the UK, and it will be difficult to get around that problem. Someone else here may have more advice though.

Comment: @ZachLipton, it's looking good, write it up!

Comment: "I'm going to apply the visa in July end or Aug end when I get my salary": That's not necessary.  You should be submitting several months of bank statements to show a stable pattern in your bank balance.  If they see that then it doesn't matter so much what the actual balance is when you apply for the visa.  Also, if they see you get paid regularly, it won't matter if the statement shows your balance shortly before you're paid.  There's a great answer about this from [Gayot Fow](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), to the question that Zach Lipton linked to.

Comment: If you look at the "Ideal Case" chart in [the answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/19560) @phoog is talking about, it actually cuts off just before a payday. Despite that, it obviously represents a regular income, routine expenses less than income, and steadily increasing savings. A very healthy bank account.

Comment: I get paid regularly every month .

Comment: My savings have gone up from May month till now

Comment: What is the cost of your flight? What is the cost of your accommodation?

Answer (score 2):

First, please read [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) That will tell you all about what they're looking for in your finances.

Obtaining a personal loan is a bad strategy. As that answer discusses, they will want to know where large deposits into your bank account come from. A loan for the purpose of padding your account will cast further doubt on your intention to return home and will not help the situation. They want to see that you have sufficient funds to make the trip and are not likely to overstay or work illegally in the UK. Holding somebody else's money does not demonstrate that.

More generally, a visa officer is going to be very concerned about your plans to spend a huge chunk of your savings on a 10-day trip to the UK. You say your trip will cost just £417 (does this include airfare?), which seems extremely low to me, especially since you plan to stay in a hotel. That's just ~£42/day for hotel, food, transportation, and all other expenses. I would say that your new application is likely to run into trouble on the basis of your finances.

As for hiring a consultant, the danger is that there are a lot of unqualified and/or unscrupulous consultants who will try to take advantage of you. Some will take your money and give you nothing in return. Others may encourage you to submit an application with false documents and get you banned from the UK. Be extremely cautious before hiring anybody. Others are even known to never submit your application and simply forge a refusal letter to send to you. Some members here advise hiring a member of the [UK Law Society](http://www.lawsociety.org.uk/) with experience in immigration; these are fully qualified UK lawyers. Their services won't come cheap though, and would burn through the funds you have saved for your trip.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is not to show a specific amount as "balance" it is to show that you have steady income and expenses in the home country.

This shows that you have *established ties*.

For example, if each month there is rent deduction, credit card fees, car loan, interest payments, salary and then there are other normal transactions of someone actively living here - this is more important than an account that has a huge balance, but no transactions.

It is **especially bad** if you have a large influx of funds (called fund parking) and this can lead to outright rejection of your application. So please don't borrow money just to prop up your bank account.

The idea when showing funds is that showing you have *access to funds* so that you can cover the expenses of your trip.

This means you can show that for example, the flight is paid for by your host, and you have _______ in UK pounds in cash; you have _______ UK pounds available to you in savings and an additional _______ UK pounds on your credit card that you can utilize.

For converting, use onada.com and mention the rate used.

Keep in mind that the officer is trying to determine if you are trying to immigrate illegally. Any kind of obligations that you have on you, or family ties, or a business are evidence that you are unlikely to stay beyond your remit.

They are very keen on signs of deception - such as large deposits and things like having a mountain of paperwork as supporting documents; so please don't try to pad your application.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for loans from banks or friends to pad your account when applying for UK visas is not a bright idea.

They even have a term for it, they call it [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications), it is seen as a (mild) deception, and it is one of the potential clauses of immediate denial of a visa.

My sis-in-law, that is foreign, applied to a UK visitor visa to visit her brother, and loaned money too, to the tune of 6K Euros, and her application was dismissed on the grounds of she having insufficient funds for the stay. It probably did not help seeing the money coming from two different sources days before the application, that she has little expenses here, sends most of the money abroad, and that she specified an address of friends, and not the family house.

They asked her for 12 months of her bank balance, and obviously, for any candidate, they are looking over sustainability and regular income over time and not for magical sums appearing suddenly before the application.