# Can I get UK visitor visa using personal loan?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have to write my Plab 2 exam in UK. I don't have any bank balance and properties the only choice i have is applying for the personal loan. I have my booking confirmation for my plab 2 exam and loan approval details from the bank. So is its possible to het UK visitor visa using bank loan. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because UK visa examiners look for a consistent financial picture that demonstrates ties to the home country, taking out a loan to fund travel is a poor idea, with little chance of success. Start your research by reading [this prior question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73037/visitor-visa-previously-refused-due-to-lack-of-funds-and-ties-to-home-country-w?rq=1).

Comment: Immigration people aren't stupid. This is another relevant question: [What is 'funds parking' in the context of UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications), and check the tag [proof-provenance-of-funds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-provenance-of-funds).

Comment: Note: if your country has not tradition of having bank accounts, or personal bank accounts (e.g. until marriage), it is not a problem. Your application is checked by people which have local knowledge, and so they know what to look for to get your financial situation. Check also your local embassy website, they may have extra explanation how to handle such local cases. If you want to make such trip, you have some money available.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The OP is asking about *borrowing* funds, not how to overcome not having a bank account at all

Comment: @Traveller: could you borrow money if you have nothing as guarantee? Many questions I see here they use similar schema because fund are in family accounts/shop/under the bed/...

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi It would generally be unusual for a retail (high street) bank to require a guarantee for a personal loan - such lending products are designed & priced as unsecured facilities,  I can’t answer for banking practice in the OP’s case as their country of residence is not given. Many visit visa applications are assessed in a UK decision-making centre https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/list-of-ukvi-international-application-points-and-decision-making-centres/list-of-ukvi-international-application-points-and-decision-making-centres-accessible-version rather than locally

Comment: @Traveller: About decision ok, but I was in impression that they do like the US: local consular office will check the documentation (they known better about original documents), and the decision is done homeland (to prevent collusion and blackmails). And for the first point: I would take all money of all of them and go to an other city rich. (It is a joke, but we have pawnshops for a reason). In any case I'm surprised. Could you give some links? I'm curious to see how the prevent frauds

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi We’re probably veering off topic now, but do you mean *loan application fraud* or *bad debt*?  The latter is mitigated by eg affordability assessment & creditscore-based decision-making; the former by eg identity & address checks. Obviously both risks can never be eliminated 100%. Referring to local input on financials, the caseworker guidance https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf#page24 talks about ‘documents’ and speaks to anti-money laundering checks.

Answer (score 11):

This is a very bad idea and is 100% certain to result in a refusal. You’ll be wasting the £100 application fee, *and* a refusal on your travel history would make it (much) harder to get a visa in future.

Do yourself a favour, cancel the bank loan and start saving instead (if you can afford to make loan repayments, you can afford to save). Wait at least 6 months and/or until you have a solid financial history before you apply.

As others have commented, there are many questions on this site on the topic, including this one [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) which covers all the key aspects