# Refusal of UK Standard Visitor Visa, reapply after previous refusal?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-of-funds

I'm living in Turkey and i planned a holiday with my wife.Our visa refused today.I went to London 2 years ago so i got visa before.I think its all about income and savings.What i must do before reapply?How can i show an evidence for my savings?Is that needed for savings?(I know that this is needed for income.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your 10,000TRY deposit looks like 'funds parking'. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications

Comment: @brhans There are 27 days to our holiday.How can i prove that money is my savings for that holiday?

Comment: @pnuts No,first one is my letter and second one is the first page of my wife's letter.

Comment: Where did the money come from? A payment from someone you're doing freelance work for, family, transferred from another account? If you only showed that account it looks like you're spending your entire savings on this trip, and they don't like that, either.

Comment: You need to show that the money is yours and is available for you to spend. So for example if it came from another account of yours, show bank statements for that account.

Comment: @nkjt I got that money from my mother.

Comment: @brhans Money came from my mother.Adding her as sponsor to my application can help me for my visa?

Comment: I think your case is honestly hopeless until your personal situation changes.  Re-applying would be a waste of your time and money. You have basically no personal savings (According to letter, taking away what your mother gave you). They don't believe you're getting the income you claimed. You need to show regular income and savings. Read the brilliant answer (with illustrations) to this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/  it shows what sort of pattern you should show in your bank account.

Comment: @nkjt My wife has an uncle who live in London.Getting an invitation letter from him can help us or not?

Comment: This is a straight-up, full-on, classic provenance of funds refusal with a dollop of funds parking for seasoning. Dupified. Hammered.  See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications.

Comment: @nkjt, next time please use that comment as an answer. I think it's a pretty good comment. As long as the question is not a duplicate, you can make an upvotable answer by fleshing out your comment, thanks