# Required financial support for a Schengen visa to visit Norway

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, proof-of-funds, norway

I am travelling to Norway in January, along with four friends. It will be a 9-day trip. I have confirmed return tickets and booked all the necessary accommodation.

I am aware that I have to submit my bank statement for the last 6 months, along with the visa application. What is an appropriate amount of money to have in the account, so that I'm not rejected because of a low balance? Flights/accommodation are already paid in full.

I'll be applying to the Norwegian Embassy in Delhi.

Comment: There's no way for you to put that information to use now! Submit the bank statements you have **without** trying to doctor the ending balance they show. Submitting bank statement that show a big unexplained deposit right at the end is **worse than** a bank statement with a "somewhat low" ending balance -- it raises suspicions of [funds parking](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications).

Comment: You should have been warned to **not pay for flights or accommodation** until after your visa is approved. Paying for them in advance increases your risk of being refused a visa (because the consulate expects the money for these to be in your bank account) and if your visa is refused, you may lose most or all of that money.

Comment: Flights, yes. But, it is not mentioned that I should not pay for accommodation. Anyway, I paid for the tickets as it has a very minimal cancellation charge. And please check my comment to Ali Awan's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the website where you could get all the visa information if applying in India:

[Norway](http://www.norwayemb.org.in/studywork/visaandresidence/Schengen-Visa1/Checklist-tourism-visa/#.WDBpe7J97IV)

> What is an appropriate amount of money to have in the account?

Actually most Schengen countries require at least 50 to 60 Euros per day plus air travel expenses. Norway is one of the most expensive countries to visit, therefore if you are visiting for 9 days you have to have 600 to 700 euros plus the cost of your airline ticket. Nowadays most travel agents and tour operators suggests to show at least 2500 euros if you are visiting for 10 to 15 days.

Although these are the minimum requirement to satisfy the visa officer that you can maintain yourself during your stay in Schengen states, you still need to convince the visa officer that you earned all these money lawfully in India by providing at least last 6 months bank statements along with official maintenance letter signed by the bank manager:

**1** **If employed** :

- Employment contract with payslips last 3 to 6 months.
- Leave permission from employer
- Income Tax Return (ITR) form or Certificate of Income Tax deducted at
  the source of salary

**2** **If self employed**

- Company registration certificate with relevant authorities plus copy
  of your business license
- Company bank statement of the latest 6 months plus maintenance
  certificate
- Income Tax Return (last 2 to 3 years)

> Flights/accommodation are already paid in full. Can I still be
>   rejected because of a low balance?

Yes, it is written in all Schengen visa application that "compliance with required documents doesn't necessarily means that a visa would be issued".

Also it is advisable from most Schengen embassies/consulates that do not purchase any tour package and airline ticket until a visa has been approved, same is written in embassy of Norway visa document checklist:

**" (Do not buy the ticket until a visa has been granted. Note: If the application is approved, the visa will be issued according to the dates on the booking)."**

Comment: I went ahead with paying for the tickets as they have a very minimal cancellation charge. Will it help if I mention this in the cover letter, saying that the tickets are already paid for?

Comment: @Naren, yes it can be really helpful if you are frequent traveller to schengen countries. There is absolutely nothing wrong purchasing a ticket and writing 2 sentences in your covering letter that you have already purchase your ticket, but again you will be held liable for outcome of your visa application. Good luck :)

Comment: Visa was approved :)
Anyway, I had some last minute deposits into my account. I mentioned the reason for the same in the cover letter.

Comment: @Naren happy to heard that :), and thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 6):

Your account has to show a **pattern** of your steady income which exceeds your reasonable expenses. This is more important than the balance. This shows that you have a job to return to (which makes you less likely to become an illegal immigrant).