# Coded Landing Help

Tags: uk, us-citizens, overstaying, visa-free-entry, repeat-visits

I’m a US citizen and have visited the UK 2-3 times a year for the last 6 years to visit my now husband. After a holiday in Europe, I had a layover in London. When landing, I told the IO this, and he commented on my visits and gave me a coded landing with “forty eight hours” noted.

I fell ill from a virus contracted on vacation, and had to remain in the UK for 3 weeks after my initial flight. I have a doctors note and spoke to Voluntary Departures while in the UK previously.

I now plan to visit again, three months after my previous visit. Will this brief overstay cause me to be refused entry? Or if I come with all documentation should I be okay?

Comment: I’m not sure anyone can answer this with any certainty. The usual advice for visa-free nationals wanting to return after a brush with Immigration leading to a worry over possible denial of entry, is to apply for a visa Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89908/what-does-the-following-uk-leave-stamp-mean

Comment: Thank you. I have read all of the posts that I could find regarding this issue. I know it is impossible to predict, yet wanted to hear stories of people being let in without a need for detention. Has this ever happened?

Comment: Were you billed by NHS and did you (or your insurance) pay the bill? The UK has been cracking down on this lately. And can you show the passport stamp from your previous landing?

Comment: @michaelhampton I previously studied on a Tier 4 Visa, so was registered at the local hospital- so no bill was given. Is this good or bad? And the stamp has "forty eight hours" hand-written on a coded landing.

Comment: @Senegence847 please keep using the same account.

Comment: @Senegence847 Were you treated in A&E or by your GP? Those NHS services are free to all, but hospital treatment is not https://www.nhs.uk/using-the-nhs/nhs-services/visiting-or-moving-to-england/visitors-from-outside-the-european-economic-area-eea/ Assuming your Tier4 visa had expired when you were treated and you were in the UK as a visitor, AFAIK you were not entitled to free non-A&E hospital treatment.