# My Wife and kids Uk visa refusal

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I am going to Uk to play cricket as an Amateur Player from last 2 years. This year also i got my visa. This time after my visa approval, the club inviting me were happy to invite my Wife and kids aged 7 years and other kid 6 months (infant).

I applied their visa on priority as they can travel with me. They never travelled abroad. this is their first international travel.

I Work in Income Tax Department here in India. 
we submitted both of us bank statements, It Returns, My pay slips., Recent  LIC payments, My elder daughter Study certificate and thier birth certificates.

Thier visas got refused, Explaining there is a large amount deposited suddenly in recent month, No proof of Accommodation and stuff. No Proof of supporting.

But , We are Genuine.

1)We took loan ammount from our gold and deposited it in my account, Apart from salary. The same account was kept for mine and i got visa.

2)If my account has that large ammount deposit issue, My wife's account is so clear and with good funds.

3) The club inviting us clearly mentioned the details of stay and food with addresses and numbers. They didn't get any call.

4)We stated, they will be returning after 2 months because my daughters school re opens here. We have given study certificate also.

How come a Central Government employee won't return or his wife or kids who are studying here in india.

Its so upset and disappointing after spending time and lot of money for priority. More over after everything planned for a nice trip with family.

Can any one suggest. What best i can do.

Comment: Sorry for your situation however you fell afoul of what we here call funds parking. Funds parking is usually fatal mistake that dooms many a UK application.

Comment: Hi, this type of UK refusal is very common and we have a lot of depth in it. You can see the various linked articles above that give an explanation, if you think that your case is different (which I doubt), you can scan and redact and upload your refusal notice and then ask for this question to be reopened.

Comment: @Sheik Paul.  Thank you for the Reply. What is funds parking. I have the Bill or Reciept that we converted the gold savings into cash and deposited into bank. But what can i do now. Should i Reapply for visa. If so what care can i take.

Comment: You should have showed the receipts with initial application. Funds Parking is putting in big sums into your account just before visa application **without** explaining the source of the money. Read how it happened to me [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-uk-previously-refused-should-i-apply-fo). I will advise you think carefully before. You are young family, all of you traveling together makes them think you will not return. You don't want a 2nd denial in a row for them. Next trip apply for them with all documents for best chances.