# uk standard visit visa refused, can a us citizen still enter the country?

Tags: visas, uk

I am a US citizen who applied for a 6 month standard visitor visa. Due to some clerical errors on my application, I was refused the visa. I do not have time or they money before my scheduled travel plans (I leave for Germany in less than 3 weeks, will be travelling in the Schengen zone, and then plan to enter the UK about a month and a half later after my first travels), to apply for another visa. I was wondering if my visa refusal will effect my entrance into the UK. I do know that US citizens are granted 6 months leave-to-enter at border control.

Comment: Was there a particular reason (e.g., prior refusal, minor criminal record, change of nationality) that you applied at all? Most Americans just show up, as you consider doing now.

Comment: no, i have no prior refusals or criminal history. the reason i applied for the standard visit visa was because i wanted to leave and enter the country at my leisure, taking side trips to portugal and other schengen countries (for a about a week at a time) while still being allowed to come into the uk for the alloted 6 months

Comment: I think if you had come here first, we would have suggested showing up anyway. I've made zigzag trips to Europe (UK-mainland-UK-mainland-UK) without border guards making any comment at all. I did this all in one summer, so it didn't look like an attempt to glue consecutive 6 months stays into something longer.

Comment: +1.  What you're describing is not that unusual.  Besides, I have heard, various places, that applying for a visa when one is not required is suspicious in itself.  Visa free or VoA agreements exist exactly to eliminate such situations.

Comment: I guess you're a prime candidate to read [my story](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-uk-previously-refused-should-i-apply-fo). It can be done however beware the perils and have your "i-s" dotted and your "t-s" crossed. The chances you will be stopped and given and taken to secondary controls are very high.

Comment: What were these "clerical errors"? there are some errors that the UK takes a very dim view on because they assume they are deliberate lies.