# Second UK visa refusal under V4.2(a) and (b); what can I change?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My visa application to visit for training and taking exams has been refused twice, on grounds that the cost of my trip represents three times more my stated disposable income. This is the information U had provided on the application form:

Salary: £964
Monthly expenditures: £535 (I actually don't spend it all, unless it's an emergency)
Disposable income: £428 as per the ECO calculation after deducting my expenses from my income
Stated trip cost: £1500

However, I wrote £535 as a rough estimate. I send money home to my family sometimes, and I normally save all my salary. I earn extra income from tips and allowances, and receive a food allowance, too, which I did mention. I don't think that this was considered, although it's evident on my pay slips which show £200 food allowance and service charge, and £220 per week in tips.

I want to visit for 4 days in July to attend a training, and 2 days in Septmeber to sit an exam. The cost of the trip came to be £1500 and includes flights, hotel, and food. I have already paid in advance for flights, accommodation, and training fees, and I attached the receipts.

1. In my next application, should I reduce my monthly expenditures?
2. Should I reduce the cost of the trip to only food and ground transportation, and state that the flights and hotel are paid for, attaching receipts as evidence?
3. Will this be enough proof to show that I am not planning to spend more than I can afford?

Note that I have £4500 accessible through my debit card and £4000 available on my credit card. I can obviously afford this trip but how can I correct how I appear financially?

[image: Photo of refusal letter page 1]
[image: Photo of refusal letter page 2]

Comment: Upload your refusal letters or risk the question being closed down. Take time to read similar questions and answers here, your case does not appear unique. Are you sure about 4.2(b)? `V 4.2 The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a genuine visitor. This means that the applicant:
(a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit; and
(b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home`;Have you previously visited UK? Your main problem is not funds, they believe you will abscond and thats tough to overcome.

Comment: Reducing your claimed monthly spend is unlikely to help. The visa officer will look at your application _and_ your previous application and say, "Well, last week, this person said they had disposable income of £428 per month and we decided they couldn't afford the trip. Now, they're suddenly claiming to have £600 (or whatever number) per month available. I don't believe that their circumstances have changed that much in a couple of weeks."

Comment: i have uploaded a copy of the second refusal

Comment: So it was 4.2 (a)+(c) not (b) like you stated in your question. That's why we like to see the original scan. Your questions are thus fully addressed by the canonical earlier linked. To add to it, I strongly suggest you do not apply for another one year or so because once you start looking desperate, things can get ugly. You're not going to the UK anytime soon. I wouldn't give you a UK visa if I were an ECO, and I'm pretty lenient.

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie i did try to show i was a genuine visitor i gave receipts of course payments,email conversation with the school from 2016, course acceptance letter etc, i was in dublin 3months ago. Am disappointed they think i am not genuine,if its because of the money i guess i will give it a rest.

Comment: @exam I feel your pain. I also had a ridiculous refusal and dustup with UK immigration you can read about here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-uk-previously-refused-should-i-apply-fo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **1. with my next application, should i reduce my monthly spend?**

Obviously the monthly spending you report on the visa application must accurately reflect your real monthly spending. You should be able to attach supporting evidence for this that matches your real expenditure. Your aim is to give the ECO a clear understanding of your real expenditure.

Taking your question literally: If you could, from now on, reduce your actual expenditure and thereby save more money from your income - then in some months time you would be able to produce bank statements and so on that show this real reduced expenditure. This might help a little with a future visa application.

> **2. Should i reduce my cost of the trip to only food and transport**

As above, apportioning the cost of your trip between pre-paid and future expenditure is not helpful to you. The question concerning the ECO is whether you have demonstrated that you can afford the overall total expenditure for the sake of 4-days training.

I believe that advice to visa applicants is to NOT buy tickets and accommodation until after you have succeeded in obtaining a visa. If I am right, ignoring this advice is likely to harm your application.

> **4. Will this be enough proof to show that am planning to spend more than i can afford**

(what happened to point 3?)

I think you need to more clearly and accurately set out the overall picture of your real financial situation. Its not really a case of moving numbers from one place to another, it is necessary to be both clear and ideally to do so in a way that isn't contradictory or inconsistent with previous applications - or to provide evidence that adequately explains such apparent discrepancies.

This may now be hard to do without expert advice (which usually means from a registered UK lawyer with experience in the field)

However, you also need to address the other issues raised by the ECO.

- Provide evidence of strong ties to your home country.
- Deal with any other points raised in both recent refusals.

Comment: @RedGrittlyBrick i should probably have used some expertise advice from the start. i don't even spend that much at all uuurrggh!! Just for clarity , i did provide passport copies of my family members and money exchange receipts which clearly showed the receivers location to be my home country ,so it didn't make sense to me that the ECO asked for the whereabouts of my family ,did they really go through all the documents i provided?