# Do I need a UK visa after being refused entry 10 years ago?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, denial-of-entry, mexican-citizens

I am a Mexican citizen and, when I was 18 years old, I wanted to visit Europe. starting with the UK. Unfortunately, I was refused entry to the UK and sent back home on the next plane because I could not prove I had enoough money for my stay and I lied about meeting a person in the UK.

Now I have travelled around the whole world, USA, Canada, Europe (with the exception of the UK), Asia etc. Ten years after what happened in the UK, I'd like to go back. I have flight from India to London in October and I'd love to be in London for 5 days more or less.

I don't want to spend money on the UK visa. It's been a lot of years and I have a nice job and enough money in the bank. I have been travelling a lot for the last 6 years ago and I haven't had any problems.

Should I get a UK visa or not? As a Mexican citizen, I don't need a visa to get into the UK and a lot of years since I had this issue with the UK border.

Comment: When was the date of your last refusal? Also, in your refusal letter, does it say you are banned from entering the UK for 10 years? Personal recommendation: I'd get a visa, so you can explain the past entry refusal and secure entry clearance in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother with a visa if I were you after so many years.

That said, collect **all** available proof of your ties to Mexico in an A4 soft binder (financial ties, employment contract, marriage certificate and everything else) and bring them to the border to show if requested (don't present the pile of documents upfront).

Also bring all available documentation proving the purpose of your visit, including contact details and invitations from any people you'll meet. Make sure they're available on the phone if need be.

If you do this, you should be OK, but expect to be delayed and be asked (potentially personal) questions. ***Never*** lie or try deflecting any question, no matter what.

**See [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89879/39782) and [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109194/can-someone-enter-the-u-k-visa-free-after-being-denied-a-visitor-visa) for useful reference**

That said, a visa will always be the safer option, as it will essentially clear your negative records.

Comment: Honestly although you referenced my case, I think his is way worse than mine. In my case I was only refused a visa on funds parking, and subsequently traveled to the UK visa free. He was denied entry, and admitted lying to immigration. I'd say his chances of being denied entry if he goes visa free are 50%. A mitigating factor is he was young and it was a decade ago. I would err on the side of getting a visa.

Comment: @TheZealot I wouldn't say his case is way worse. Yes, he committed deception, but it's also been longer since. If he presents everything he can to prove his purpose for visiting as well as his ties back home, ***and*** answers all questions clearly and honestly, he should make it.

Comment: Still, one ought to mention that presenting the evidence in a visa application will likely be much less stressful than doing so after arriving in the airport.