# UK visa ban based on an allegedly non-genuine Dutch permit

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, iranian-citizens, deception, visa-bans

New Edit/information: I am attaching a picture of the original refusal letter. Personally it makes no sense to me as to why they would think it's a fake permit, especially since she personally went to a police station and got it right then and there. Currently we are trying to find someone in a Dutch embassy or elsewhere to obtain an official letter stating the permit is real. As you can see in the original letter they believe the permit is for a male and of a different nationality... Also, I believe I forgot to mention this but she is Iranian with an Iranian passport.

Side Note: I have blacked out certain parts such as her name, company/employer name, and monthly salary. But just to clarify her salary is equal to over 2,000 British Pounds. Her reason for wanting to travel to the UK was just to travel as she does that a lot and has been to a lot of places. I mean her passports are filled with stamps from all over.

My friend recently applied for a UK visa but she got rejected and banned because they claim there is a non-geniune dutch permit in her old passport. This permit is a piece of paper which she got when she went to Amsterdam in 2011. She went to Amsterdam with a schengen visa and was told she had to check in at a police station, which she did and they put the paper in her passport. She was also told to check in with a dutch embassy outside of the netherlands after she left the country, which she also did and they stamped her passport at the embassy.

The UK visa office rejected her visa once because they claimed the permit is non-geniune, she applied again explaining what the permit is and that it is not how she claims to have entered the netherlands. She also got a letter from the dutch embassy stating she entered the netherlands legally.

They refused the visa again and gave her a 10 year ban based on them claiming it's a non-geniune permit.

I'm curious if anyone else has had a similar issue with the uk visa application and if they have any advice on how to follow up and rectify the issue. I will try and attach copies of the rejection letter and the dutch permit in question.

I should also note that she knows other people who had to do the same process when going to the netherlands. As in she wasn't the only one with that permit in her passport.

Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Sash718 What’s your friend’s nationality?

Comment: @Giorgio Not really a duplicate. This is a case where the person reviewing a document thinks a document is illegitimate when it is legitimate.

Comment: @gparyani yes, but once a ban is in place, nothing can be done or suggested here, particularly not on the validity of what is being shown. When a document is considered questionable, verification is done by expert examiner. At this point, the person's only option is to seek legal advice, not random input from strangers on the internet.

Comment: What explanation did they give for their determination that the permit was not genuine?  The refusal letter is supposed to explain the officer's reasoning.

Comment: The burden of proof is on the UK authorities to prove this was a false document and in this case that you were aware it was false. False means dishonest in this case. What reasons have they given to show that this document is false?

Comment: I have no idea why this was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Your friend could try lodging a complaint by emailing at complaints@homeoffice.gsi.gov.uk, or writing to the address given here https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration/about/complaints-procedure

Comment: @Traveller Thanks for the links, I'm reading through them right now. Cheers

Comment: If the letter from the Dutch embassy does not specifically say the document is genuine, see if you can get one that does so.

Comment: @Sash716 I’m struggling to find an official source for this, however it appears that Non-EU/EEA/Swiss citizens visiting the NL for either a short or long stay, need to report to the local Aliens Police ('Vreemdelingendienst') within 3 days of arrival in the NL. The Aliens Police put a sticker into the individual’s passport stating until which date they may stay in the NL. The validity date will correspond with what is mentioned on the short-stay visa, if applicable. Does the information on the sticker in your friend’s passport correspond with the visa itself?

Comment: @Traveller An official explanation of this requirement is here (in Dutch though): https://www.politie.nl/themas/kort-verblijf-vreemdelingen-2014.html

Comment: @Traveller looking at the wording of the current refusal, it is apparent that the ECO understands that a Dutch permit is distinct from a visa. However, they believe the permit (not the visa) to be non-genuine. They would have recorded the reasons for this in a document verification report and also mentioned it in the original refusal letter. We should wait for the OP to post the original refusal before jumping to conclusions. The OP has submitted a letter from the Dutch embassy that the traveler entered legally but not that the permit in question is genuine.

Comment: @greatone I get the reason for the refusal, but I’m not jumping to conclusions, just asking questions to try to clarify. That’s why I’ve not posted an answer

Comment: Both the original refusal letter and the mentioned letter from the Dutch embassy may contain details, which are relevant. Can you please post the relevant parts thereof?

Comment: @Traveller Sorry for the late reply. What you found about the non-EU citizens visiting the NL is correct and that is what she did. The previous page of that permit is the Schengen visa she used to enter the NL. On the visa itself it says report to the police in Amsterdam within 72 hours / report back to embassy.

Also, I just checked and the Schengen Visa number matches the v.nr number which is on the permit itself. the 2758215715 number. Of course that doesn't mean much since it is handwritten and simply covered with a protective layer. 

I just made an edit/update to my post btw. Thx

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I've posted the original refusal letter. I don't have the dutch embassy letter at the moment but will try to get it. In either case we are trying to find someone in the embassy or elsewhere who can officially, and clearly, say that the permit is not fake.

Comment: @Traveller Forgot to mention that the passport number in the permit and the visa match the passport they are in. Just wanted to mention that.

Comment: @Sash716 The original refusal stated the permit was issued to a different person. Your friend needs an immigration lawyer, or to accept that they’re not getting another visa any time soon.

Comment: @Sash716 Where did your friend apply for the Dutch visa? Did she use an agency, and if so is there any possibility she was scammed?

Comment: Any updates? Any outcome?

Answer (score 12):

Your passport contained a Dutch permit that the UK authorities believe to have been issued to another person.

Firstly, you should consult with a competent immigration lawyer based in the UK. You should make efforts to obtain a Document Verification Report from the UKVI which would look something like this [DVR Sample](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/257786/dvr-completed-example.pdf). This would contain the checks performed by the UKVI which led them to their conclusions. If you think this has been an innocent  mistake by the Dutch Alien police, you will need some sort of documentary evidence to shift the burden of proof back on the UKVI.

Second, if the permit is indeed false (that means there was dishonesty involved), according to the Courts, the application would still fall to be refused under 3.6(a) because it is not necessary that the deception has been used by the applicant or that he/she is aware of that deception. In this case, you will need to make a new application (the second one) and show that the applicant was unaware that the permit was non-genuine. Refusals under 3.6(b) require knowledge of the applicant to the dishonesty. Your friend will need have to provide some evidence to show she did not know this was a false document to shift the burden of proof back on the UKVI.

To sum it up, if it there was an honest mix up, there should be no refusal. If there was deception by the Dutch police (or anyone other than the applicant), the first application would be refused under 3.6(a) but not the second under 3.6(b). If your friend was aware of the deception, the ban will not be overturned.

This is a complicated matter and would be better handled by a competent immigration attorney.

Reference: https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/2010/773.html

Answer (score 5):

Get a competent immigration attorney. There is little point soliciting opinions on such a delicate and complex matter online from nameless faceless people of varying and/or questionable competence.

Alternatively you can try to save yourself a pretty penny by complaining using the email  complaints@homeoffice.gsi.gov.uk which can be found on the [UK Visas and Immigration Complaints Procedure](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration/about/complaints-procedure#how-to-complain) webpage.

Apparently they take complaints seriously because about one month or so ago I [lodged a complaint with UK Border Force](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96671/can-a-uk-border-immigration-officer-remove-a-stop-indicator-flag/119574#119574) and it was handled very professionally and promptly and in my favor. My case however was not as serious as yours hence the recommendation to use an immigration solicitor.