# UK Border control always takes me under investigation. Why it could be?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, turkish-citizens

1. I am Turkish citizen.
2. I have Turkish Passport.
3. I live in Germany.
4. I have 2 years valid UK visa.
5. I frequently fly from Germany to London.

And each time, the UK Border Police checks my documents, then takes my passport and German card then ask me to sit in a place guarded by a police. (I think it's not detention, but still a place they put truly suspicious people.)
There they also gave me a paper which states which documents they held.

The last time, the border officer asked "In your earlier travels, did we took your documents and asked you to sit somewhere before?"
I said "Yes, every time."
Then he said "Well, I am about to do it again."

So now, I am curious. Why this keep happening to me? Is there any rule that applies to me?

Comment: Hi, [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96671/can-a-uk-border-immigration-officer-remove-a-stop-indicator-flag) may be related. We won't know exactly why though - only an officer at the border can tell you if you ask.

Comment: Like they [have been doing to me](https://www.flickr.com/photos/34477910@N03/albums/72157668735454807/with/41929674070/) three times in a row? I don’t know if in your case it will be helpful however you can [follow my solution](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96671/can-a-uk-border-immigration-officer-remove-a-stop-indicator-flag?noredirect=1&lq=1) and hope.

Comment: Have you ever applied for anything and been denied, or have you had a hard time in the past convincing them to let you in?

Comment: @Forlorn Lancer How frequently is ‘frequently’ and how long have you spent in the UK in total with this visa? Assuming it’s a 2 year Standard Visitor visa. They may suspect you are working, or that the reason(s) for your visits are not in line with those stated in your application

Comment: @Coke, No I never been denied and they asked nothing but some usual questions.

Comment: @Traveller, I spend only few days per 1 or 2 months. I am definitely not working. But I have work experience in Ireland.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen That makes a lot of sense, thanks. Probably that's what happens to me. Lets hope my case is not something serious.

Comment: @ForlornLancer Do they record your landing every time? You can tell by the entry stamp - if they do, there's a bigger rectangular stamp with the landing card code handwritten. If this is there every single time (which is **not** normal for a resident of Western Europe only visiting for a few days per month), either there is a name match between you and a criminal, or some officer really didn't like your vibes and decided to try and make your life difficult, or there's something you aren't telling us.

Comment: I don't know about the finer technical distinctions in UK law, but in US law the circumstances you describe are indeed "detention" (even if the place where you're being kept isn't a dedicated detention facility).

Comment: @Coke I will definitely check my Passport for the Rectangular stamp and let you know. There is a slight chance that my name disturbs them, it would be truly immature, but I am aware Border Police can be ordered to act immature. Officers were always different, and respectful all the time, so I am absolutely sure its not about them. And if there is a rectangular thing, I will definitely think about my past in deep.

Comment: @ForlornLancer The thing is, at passport control, they can see on the screen *if* there is a problem with you, but not *what* the problem is. For that, they have to go into the back offices and check

Comment: @phoog I suspect that in the US and UK, secondary inspection is not technically 'detention' because you are free at any time to leave, simply by withdrawing your application to enter the country.

Comment: @DJClayworth in the US, at least, you need to have the agreement of the immigration inspector before withdrawing your application to enter the country, and if you do so, you're not free to go, but rather remain in custody of CBP until you can be placed on a flight out of the country.

Comment: @Coke, My entrance stemp is rectangular but nothing was handwritten on it. Perhaps I am a less-dangerous traveller? I will fly to London again and this time I will be on alert.

Comment: @ForlornLancer Is it this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS4qvp8zNpgO9D3xL4OIUAto8l2e4yF74cRiYWkryl6viW9n_VFgQ or this? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/UKStamp.jpg/220px-UKStamp.jpg

Comment: @Coke Definitely the first one.

Comment: @ForlornLancer All of them?

Comment: @Coke No, I only have the rectangle and nothing else. I hope I am clear?

Comment: @ForlornLancer OK, that means they are **not** keeping your landing card (the blue form) when you enter - if they did, that would be one sign that they find you suspicious. Therefore, my best guess is someone flagged your name in the computer system during one entry; that is, if you haven't had any other problems with authorities inside the country

Comment: @Coke Thanks for the help, I will pay attention on 4th of december to see what happens.

Comment: @Crazydre Hey again, I wanted to let you know that I sent an email to border control as Honorary Citizen described, and the flag was removed. I passed through border control without a problem. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @ForlornLancer You should edit your change of status into your question to make it more prominent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why this keep happening to me?

Below is the verbatim response I got from Border Force Correspondence Team to my complaint. You will never find out exactly why

- > When you arrived in the UK and presented your passport it was
  >   necessary for the officer to make some enquiries in addition to
  >   considering your application for entry/admission to the UK. **I am
  >   unable to comment on the nature of these additional enquiries as it is
  >   not in the public interest to disclose the specific reasons why
  >   passengers are subject to checks.**

Is there any rule that applies to me?

- The same rules that apply to everyone and the 
  conclusion that there is a flag against your name that requires the
  immigration officer to go to the secondary control point to ascertain
  exactly why there is a flag against your name at the primary control terminal.

Comment: Thanks to your post, I was able to remove the flag. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

Hassle at Border Control is something that many of us experience at some time or other.

On the basis of the information you've provided, the question I would have would relate to why those frequent trips to the UK?   The frequency of your trips marks you out as not following usual patterns of behaviour for travellers from the country of your passport and the country of your usual residence. Border control staff are on the alert for unusual patterns of behaviour.  That alone is enough to have your file marked as suspicious.

Comment: Sorry, but there's nothing inherently suspicious about a Turkish citizen living in Germany and making frequent trips to the UK.