# Will being detained at the UK border raise a stop indicator flag?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, borders, visa-free-entry

I was detained and questioned at the UK border after attempting to travel visa-free. This may have been due to the fact that initially I said I was there for “tourism” and when asked if I had any friends there I said yes, my girlfriend whom I’m visiting. They called her up and asked her a bunch of questions. Ultimately they gave me the standard leave to enter for six months. I stayed a week, and left on time. Will this raise a stop indicator flag when I try to enter the next time?

Comment: I think this is the most important fact *Ultimately they gave me the standard leave to enter for six months*. So i don't think this is going to cause you extended questioning every time in the future

Comment: @HankyPanky I disagree. I was also given leave to enter for six months after being detained for eight hours. I was subsequently always grilled when entering until I filed an official complaint and the flag was removed. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96671/can-a-uk-border-immigration-officer-remove-a-stop-indicator-flag. He should file a complaint to have the flag removed, like I did. See link.