# Travelling 8 months after stop indicator flag

Tags: uk

I traveled to the UK on October 18th 2018 and my name got flagged on the border officer's computer. Here's why: I was a student 5 years ago but did not complete my studies, therefore my visa was curtailed and I left the UK immediately. When I entered in October, I entered using a new passport I recently obtained that allows me to enter the UK visa free.

The border officer was extremely polite..I explained that I was not really interested in what I was studying back then and that I did not overstay my visa after it was curtailed. He went to the back office and checked my records and came back after 10 minutes, he apologized for the delay, he also assured me that he requested the flag to be removed (he did also say that the system is quite slow with these requests) he said that I should not face issues next time I travel to the UK.

My question is: How long does it take for a stop indicator flag to be removed?

Answer (score 2):

> How long does it take for a stop indicator flag to be removed?

Undetermined period of time. The more important question is can he remove the indicator unilaterally? He's not going to be able to remove the flag. He's blowing hot air up your behind. Twice, actually three times they told me the same thing and did nothing about it.

You will have to go through other channels. See below for a possible solution:

[Can a UK Border Immigration Officer remove a stop indicator flag?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96671/can-a-uk-border-immigration-officer-remove-a-stop-indicator-flag/119574#119574) and

[Recently naturalized American visiting the UK, previously denied visa. Apply for entry clearance?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for/89879#89879)