# Will my fiancee require another UK visit visa?

Tags: visas, usa, uk

My fiancee (US citizen) was refused entry to the UK in November 2018. She obtained a visit visa May 24 2019 which she used to travel to the UK from August 2-August 21 2019.

She plans to visit again for three weeks in December 2019 for the holidays. Will she require another UK visit visa or may she enter as normal US citizens would?

Thanks.

Comment: What was the reason for the entry denial?

Comment: They believed she intended to overstay since we had no definitive plans on when she'd go back to the States and no return flight. We are in a completely different situation now along with being a lot more knowledgeable regarding visas and the parameters surrounding them.

Answer (score 2):

For the UK, having obtained a visa after a refusal of entry effectively resolves the problem. You can obtain another if you wish, but it is not required and probably not necessary. Keep in mind that whatever it was that caused the original refusal, you probably should not do that again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Original refusal was because they believed she would overstay her six months as we had no definitive return date and no return flight.

Comment: @LR837 Oh yes, I went back and read your old posts. You should be fine now, providing you show up with definite travel plans and return tickets.

Comment: @LR837 At this point she should also be able to use the ePassport gates as well, so it's entirely possible you won't speak to anyone.

Comment: That is something I'm definitely eager to see if it works or not. She tried to use one on August 2 but it told her to seek a member of staff, to where she was led to manual inspection. I look forward to seeing if the ePassport gate would accept her now.

Comment: @LR837 See [Can a UK Border Immigration Officer remove a stop indicator flag?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/96671/3221) regarding having a stop indicator removed from the passport. If the gate rejects her again, you should ask for this.

Comment: I looked into that before. I'll definitely remind her to ask about this if she remembers. I asked her to ask this during this visit but the excitement of being granted entry overcame that, ha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97701/discussion-between-lr837-and-michael-hampton).