# Re-entering the UK

Tags: uk, removal

I was removed from the UK for overstaying my visitors visa in 2003. After returning to Jamaica, I got married and then migrated to the United States in 2009. I’m now a naturalized American citizen.

This summer my family and friends are planning to visit Europe. We are flying into Paris, France on June 14, 2018 and want to visit a few other countries, one of those England.
We are all holders of a US passport.

Do I need to apply for a waiver to re-enter the UK, since my removal has been over 10 years ago, and I’m now traveling with a US a passport?

Comment: I suspect that you don't need to apply for anything, but you might be advised to apply for a visa even though you don't need one.  If it's granted, it will improve your chances at the border.

Comment: Related:  [Recently naturalized American visiting UK, previously refused. Should I apply for entry clearance?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-uk-previously-refused-should-i-apply-fo?rq=1)  Note the original poster's follow-up, including the fact that the immigration officers asked "have you ever had any problems with immigration anywhere?" and the fact that they were then detained at Heathrow for six hours.  ...

Comment: ... The only reason this question isn't a direct duplicate of that one is that the previous questioner had been *refused* a visa two years prior, rather than *removed* for overstaying;  but if anything, I suspect your case would be likely to arouse more suspicion with an immigration officer, rather than less.

Comment: I agree with @phoog.  You should apply for a visa, just in case. You will obviously be in their system, and they *will* be able to connect you (with your overstay) with your new American passport.  You will likely face a bit of an "up-hill battle" trying to obtain a visa, despite the fact that you have served your 10-year ban, for the simple fact that you overstayed in the past