# Entering UK 5 years after tier 4 visa was curtailed

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas

Thank you in advance for your time taken to answer my question.

First of all, I'd like to mention that I'm a dual nationality holder. (this will help you answer my question)

I was an international student undertaking my studies at the UK, however, I was not in a good place mentally then and that reflected poorly on my academic performance, ultimately leading to my tier 4 visa being curtailed. Note that I had left the UK as soon as I received my curtailment letter. ( I had only one citizenship at that time)

Fast forward 5 years, I am now a dual citizenship holder, and the citizenship I recently obtained allows me to enter the UK as a visitor visa-free, I plan on visiting my brother soon who is currently undertaking his studies there. Will I face problems with immigration control at the airport?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you nationalities?

Comment: Your situation is a little more difficult situation [than mine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-refused-should-i-appl). You will definitely face problems at immigration control, guaranteed. Whether you apply for a visa or not, you can be sure of that.

Comment: @helen What ties do you have to your country of residence? Apart from obtaining your second citizenship, how solid are your financial circumstances?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus I don't agree that the OP will necessarily have problems with UK immigration. UKVI aren't concerned with academic performance, just compliance with visa conditions. If she left the UK promptly when her visa was curtailed there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The typical advice when a visitor qualifies for visa-free entry but has concern(s) as to whether it will be granted, is to be able to show documents explaining their reason for travel and ability to support themselves during the trip to Immigration, if asked. https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control This should include proof of return to home country/onward travel.

Comment: @CannonFodder My definition of problem is she will not pass through smoothly in the couple minutes that the average traveler spends being asked routine questios by the immigration officer. She will definitely see something like a thirty minute wait because the immigration officer will definitely have to get up from their desk and go and check more details on her case from their other computers. The Primary Control Point computer will definitely flag her but it will not have details.

Comment: I was not deported and I did not overstay my visa, my visa was just cut short. I will be bringing vital documents with me (proof of return ticket, hotel reservation, plus proof that I'll be able to bare the finances of my stay). What came to my attention from someone who is well aware of immigration control procedures, is that since I'll be entering the UK as a visitor visa-free using my second citizenship, there is no way that they'll be able to trace my original citizenship back to me, as that would be quite a complex process, is that true? just wanted to double check.

Comment: @Traveller I'll have more than enough money to cover the duration of my stay, I'll be bringing other support documents as well.

Comment: `since I'll be entering the UK as a visitor visa-free using my second citizenship, there is no way that they'll be able to trace my original citizenship back to me, as that would be quite a complex process, is that true?` That is a dream

Comment: OP has not clarified nationalities, nor returned. Putting on hold.