# US to UK visting multiple times without visa

Tags: visas, usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens

I am a US citizen who is dating a UK citizen. My boyfriend attended flight school but after finishing, he moved back to the UK. I have visited the UK 3 times since he moved in January. The first time I went for a week, 10 days my second trip, and 3 weeks over summer. I have my 4th trip booked where we are also visiting other countries. I am nervous about getting denied at the UK border. I am not working in the UK, just strictly there to see my boyfriend. I have read that I am allowed there 90 out of 180 days but I'm not understanding when the 180 days starts over. Also, is there a visa I could apply for that fits my situation? I'd love to be able to keep visiting but I know I can only pull that off so many times. 
Any advice will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I have read that I am allowed there 90 out of 180 days but I'm not understanding when the 180 days starts over. ` Not correct, that is for Schengen countries. There is no such criteria for UK. There is a visitors visa you could apply for. I would not recommend it, it will not change anything. The criteria for you according to UK immigration guidance is `V 4.2 The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a genuine visitor. This means that the applicant:

(b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home`

Comment: Thank you! One last question, should I expect any trouble getting through the border on my upcoming visit?

Comment: Refer to @phoog answer he provided. I agree with him particularly `Having a job and a place to live in the US will go a long way toward dispelling such a concern`. Those unreasonable folk at UK immigration [harassed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-refused-should-i-appl) an engineer employed in the USA like me, claiming I might want to illegally stay in the UK permanently. Be abundantly well prepared to address their questions if they raise them but do not be overconfident. Immigration officers can be unpredictable.

Answer (score 9):

The 90/180 rule applies in the Schengen area, not the UK.

For the UK, you're normally admitted for six months per visit.  The immigration officer who decides whether to admit you is supposed to refuse entry if he or she finds that you are not a genuine visitor.  One thing that can lead to that conclusion is a finding that you are using frequent visits to live in the UK.

The pattern you have described does not seem close to raising such a concern.  You've been in the UK for less than a month and a half over the course of six to eight months.

Another possible concern would be that you intend to stay in the UK to live with your boyfriend.  Having a job and a place to live in the US will go a long way toward dispelling such a concern if it ever comes up, but your history of short visits may also work in your favor.