# How to show share proceeds in bank statements for UK visa

Tags: visas

I will be applying for a visitor visa to UK in Feb 2019.In my bank statements there are entries for credit and debit of proceeds related to share transactions that I have performed during last 6 months.Since these are relatively large amounts compared to account balance, how do I explain this in my application? Do I need to attach the contract notes for those specific transactions or is there any other way? Also I shift most of my salary to my savings account, so there is only minimum balance maintained in this salary account.Do I need to show statements from both salary and savings account in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do I explain this in my application?

You answered the question yourself in your subsequent question, i.e. you attach the statement from your brokerage account which show dividend payments etc. When we say bank statements, we do not only refer to traditional bank statements but also financial statements showing your liquidity. I personally keep very little in my checking account, most of my liquidity is in my brokerage account and I always include those. The one time I did not include my brokerage account, [my application got denied](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-refused-should-i-appl/89879#89879).

> Do I need to attach the contract notes for those specific transactions
>   or is there any other way?

Yes, that is what we call providing provenance of funds.

> Do I need to show statements from both salary and savings account in
>   this case?

It makes sense, so the connection between the two will be apparent.

> Also I shift most of my salary to my savings account, so there is only
>   minimum balance maintained in this salary account. Do I need to show
>   statements from both salary and savings account in this case?

Yes

Comment: When we say bank statements, we do not only refer to traditional bank statements but also financial statements showing your liquidity. Here by financial statements, are you referring to complete demat holding statement or statements specific for the transactions highlighted in my bank statement.Thanks for your reply

Comment: I don’t understand your question. What I mean is add any financial statements from brokerages or other institutions which show the link between large amounts entering and leaving your checking and saving accounts that you intend to submit. They like to know the **source** of large transactions. That’s all

Comment: Ok..got it.I was confused between the brokerage statement for those particular transactions and the complete financial statement of my trading account(ie the one that states that I have x amount invested in total)