# Attend a course interview (not job interview) in the UK on a Standard Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, uk

I've been granted a Standard Visitor Visa to the UK, and now need to visit the UK to attend a master course interview at a UK university. Unfortunately the university cannot arrange an online interview due to the special type of the course that requires physical attendance so as to better observe candidates' suitability.

I've checked the official guidance on the government website https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa, [image]it clearly states **business** activities such as meetings and interviews are permitted. Since my interview is not for business (it's not a job interview and I'm now unemployed), but for a master course, now I'm not entirely sure if I can visit the UK for the course interview on the visit visa?

Also I'm now unemployed, would it be problematic during my landing interview at the border?

Comment: I think you’re being over analytical. Note that the rules cannot cover every single scenario. To attend a masters course interview, a students visa is not the visa required. It does not meet the criteria for students visa. It can only be addressed by the visitor visa. Being unemployed is not a positive, however I have visited the UK while unemployed and they did ask me however I had funds so it was not a problem. Do you have ample funds?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I have ample funds to support my trip. How do I prove that when I land if asked? What documents do I need to prove upon arrival? When I first applied for the visa, I applied for tourism purpose and provided financial evidence (I was employed then) so I've got the visa and used it once. Do you believe they'll ask me for any evidence of proof? I'm not employed with any paid contracts but I'm volunteering for a charity (not paid), does this help? Thanks!

Comment: Carry bank statements etc along with you plus some **cash**. The documents I usually carry can be [found here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-refused-should-i-appl/89879#89879).

Comment: DOCUMENTS I CARRIED ALONG

I had the original visa refusal letter from 2015, three months of current bank statements from each of my three checking accounts plus brokerage account , three months of mortgage statements, signed invitation letter, marriage certificate, return ticket, CASH plus credit cards (they did say they prefer debit card to credit card because it's access to your own money and not a loan unlike a credit card),

Comment: Thanks! I think in theory I should be allowed to enter without the financial documents, since they've already checked my financial status when applied for the visa. But I guess it does not harm to bring the documents you mentioned, just to be safe!

Comment: Unfortunately that is not correct. Even in theory you should have the documentation ready to provide to immigration when asked for it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the rules cannot cover every single scenario.To attend a masters course interview, a students visa is not the visa required. It does not meet the criteria for students visa. It can only be addressed by the visitor visa.

Being unemployed is not a positive, however I have visited the UK while unemployed and they did ask me however I had funds so it was not a problem.

Carry bank statements etc along with you plus some cash. The documents I usually carry can be [found here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-refused-should-i-appl/89879#89879).