# I am a student who wants to apply for a Standard Visitor visa in UK, so i would like to know if the answers provided in my context is enough

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

1. What is your employment status? **A student**
2. Do you have another income or any savings? **I do not have any other income or savings**
3. How much money are you planning to spend on your visit to the UK? **1000.00 GBP** I plan on spending 2 weeks, so does quoting this amount makes sense?
4. What is the total amount of money you spend each month? **80.00 GBP** I quoted this amount because I spend on only food, accommodation and fees are catered for by the government.
5. Will anyone be paying towards the cost of your visit? **Yes**
6. Who is paying towards the cost of your visit? Someone I know (for example, 
   family or friend)
7. How much money will they be paying towards your visit? **1000.00 GBP**
8. Why are they helping to pay for your visit? **As a close relative, it is their 
   way of showing me love.**

Comment: Onua, as a fellow Ghanaian I can tell you the profile you’re presenting here is one that will likely be refused the visa. Make sure you have your personal bank statement even if the cash it contains is small.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen Okay well noted. my visa in the country of residence now ends in August so will you recommend i go back to Ghana and apply to the UK?

Comment: Yaw I don’t know how that will help you. If you have not yet graduated, it might even be better to apply from where you are because they might believe it is not likely you will abandon your degree so close to graduation. Applying from Ghana gives no advantage. Make sure you put together a strong application. They don’t give Ghanaians much benefit of the doubt because so many of our counteymen overstay in UK. [Read this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-refused-should-i-appl)

Answer (score 4):

These are the issues I see:

- You didn't say the purpose of your visit. This needs to be true, and it must make sense that your sponsor would spend £1000 for that purpose.
- You will be expected to name your sponsor and their relation to you (e.g. friend, brother, mother, uncle, etc.).
- You need to submit your own [bank statements and proof of sources of income](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/3221) even if you have little income, in addition to your sponsor's bank statements and proof of sources of income.
- Your sponsor should not transfer money to you before you receive the visa stamp. Doing so almost guarantees a visa refusal.
- You are not guaranteed to receive a visa even if you do everything right. It's very difficult for people in your circumstances (university student with little income and savings) to receive a visa. You can only make your application as good as you can possibly do. If you don't have the ability to make a strong application, it may be better to not apply, so that you do not risk having a visa refusal on your record that may harm your ability to receive visas later in life.

Comment: the purpose is to spend time with the family, visit exciting places and have a good feel of British culture.                                                                                                           
The sponsor is an uncle of mine

Comment: @Yaw Owusu You should consider including proof of the relationship and evidence of ongoing contact between you. Nevertheless, even with a sponsor, as Honorary World Citizen comments, your profile means your chances of success may be limited

Comment: @Traveller what kind of proof can you explain a bit further. we not bear the same surname though so i can not use birth certificate. and yes i have a lot of chat with him

Comment: @Yaw Owusu Presumably your uncle’s and father’s birth certificates would show parent(s) in common.

Answer (score 1):

> **1000.00 GBP** I plan on spending 2 weeks, so does quoting this amount makes sense?

That seems quite low to me: about 70 GBP/day. It might be worth breaking it down into accommodation, food, transport, admission to the places you plan to visit, and other shopping (souvenirs, gifts, batteries for your camera, etc).

Comment: Accommodation, food, visit to places of interest will be catered for by the sponsor. it is 70 GBP/month not day..

Comment: Huh? The text in yellow is a direct quote from your question. I arrived at 70 by taking 1000 and dividing by the number of days in 2 weeks, then rounding.

Comment: Oh, I missed that bit. That's pretty important.

Comment: @PeterTaylor so kindly help out ..what will be the reasonable amount to quote for two weeks visa when the accommodation, food, admission and others are taking care of by my sponsor.

Comment: @Yaw, "*taken care of*" is ambiguous. If you're going to stay in your uncle's house, you can put 0 for accommodation (or maybe the price of taking your uncle and his family out for dinner as a thank-you) and add a note explaining why. If you're going to stay in a hostel and your uncle is paying, look on a site like booking.com to get a realistic estimate. Similarly the other items. If they interview you and ask you to justify your answer, having done your own research will make you more credible than having asked a stranger.

Comment: @PeterTaylor okay

Answer (score 0):

I heard from people, for fully sponsored applicants, they only need to put amount that they will pay for personally on the "how much money are you planning to spend on your visit?" question.
So, in your case, you just need to put 0 on the 3rd question. And put the total cost on the next question about the money that sponsor will be paying towards.

Actually this question is prone to be misinterpreted though. On my application, I also did the same thing as you did but still waiting for the outcome.

How about your visa, did you manage to get it?