# After a UK Family visit visa refusal, can I still enter the UK as a US citizen visa free or will I be refused at the border?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, us-citizens

I recently applied for a UK Family Visit Visa but it got denied. We want to visit my husband parents long term but they said this:

> You have applied for entry clearance to live in the UK indefinitely. As such, I am not satisfied that you genuinely intend a short visit only to the UK and that you will leave the UK at the end of the visit. Your application is refused under paragraphs V4.2(a) and (c) of Appendix V.
>
> You state that you intend to work in the UK. Therefore I am not satisfied that you will not undertake any prohibited activities set out in V 4.5 – V 4.10. Your application has been refused under paragraph V4.2(d) and V4.5(a)

So our intention was to visit family and while visiting family apply for leave to remain status since we can only do it in the UK and not from the US. We thought we needed a visa to apply for that so when they asked us on our application if we are going to stay I said yes because my intentions in the future was to stay and work when if the leave to remain is granted. But I didn’t know it was a question for that visa I thought it was just a personal question.

Would if be bad if I told the border this if I got detained? Since I know they will ask me how and why I got denied and what were my intentions on this visit? I will have a return ticket just in case the leave to remain was not accepted and done in time so I’m not there living illegally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recently naturalized American visiting the UK, previously refused. Should I apply for entry clearance?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-refused-should-i-appl). Yes they will detain you for anywhere from 30 minutes to 8 hours like they did to me. If you have your financial documents and everything properly organized it could on the shorter end. If you’re not properly organized or very unlucky, you could be denied entry.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. A Family visa is to live with your partner in the UK https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse but overall your question reads as if you intended to visit and applied for a Standard Visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa? It may help you get better answers if you post a copy of your refusal notice with personal details blanked out.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because the OP is seriously interested in expatriating to the UK. Unfortunately, I think her chances of getting a vanilla tourist visa on arrival are damaged by the failed Family Visa (was that appropriate when the family lives in the USA?) as in theory only the husband and child can remain indefinitely.

Comment: The explanation you gave for your visa refusal doesn't make sense. Please post photos of every page of the refusal letter, with your personal information blacked out.

Comment: You can use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, so that you can easily edit your question.

Comment: Can you? Yes. Will they probably notice this refusal and refuse you at the border? Also yes.

But honestly, this sounds like you've started off going about this all wrong. (I don't think you can apply or ILR on a temporary visa anyway) and should seek professional advice.