# Canadian citizen, on US no-fly list. What can I do in order to be allowed on flights which go through US airspace?

Tags: usa, air-travel, canada, legal, routes

My father and I, both Canadian citizens, were denied to board a direct Turkish Airlines flight from Istanbul to Toronto non-stop without any prior warning or information. Literally, at the gate, we were told that we were put on a no-fly list by Homeland Security because my father and I own a cargo business together located in eastern Turkey. Apparently, the area was suddenly declared a red zone (danger zone) and all business owners in the district were put on a no-fly list.

The only way we were able to make it back to Canada was via Scandinavian northern routes flying close to the Arctic. Cost thousands of dollars, hundreds of hours and months in moral and mental pain. We even had an issue sending my 1-year-old daughter on a flight with her mother to visit Turkey after that. I was told my one-year-old daughter's name was put on a no-fly list; when I heard this, I just felt like fainting and was holding myself not to cry in front of all these people.

On top of all of this even when we are able to fly back and forth via 2-3 stop northern routes to Canada we are now getting interrogated for 4-5 hour periods at our own airports by our own Canadian customs agents every single time. Life has been horrible with this issue handicapping us to live our normal lives. We are honest business people that have nothing to do with any illegal acts we have always been law-abiding citizens and will continue to do so.

Can anyone Help with this issue, or has anyone ever had any similar experience? Any resolution?

Comment: How did a nonstop from Istanbul to Toronto pass over U.S. airspace?  Wouldn't the great-circle route involved stay well to the north of the States?

Comment: @Sean the great circle route is not that far north of the US border.  In particular, the airport is probably less than 50 km from US airspace.

Comment: To elaborate on what @phoog is saying, Toronto is right on Lake Ontario, which is the international border.

Comment: Would it be possible to land in Canada just a little bit further to the North, thus avoiding flying through the US? And it would probably be shorter and less expensive than hopping around several Northern European countries.

Comment: Possible option: Fly via [Gander International Airport (YQX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gander_International_Airport)

Comment: @Sean Flights don't necessarily follow the great circle. Particularly over the Atlantic, they often dip quite a bit farther south, depending on wind conditions: if you can reduce the headwind by 50km/h (which you very often can) then covering an extra 200km over the ground on a six-hour flight still saves you the equivalent of 100km of flying. The [great circle from IST to YYZ](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=IST-YYZ) doesn't miss Maine by a whole lot, Toronto is very close to the border and planes may well end up approaching from the south-east or south-west, depending on the weather.

Comment: Try contacting your MP's office.  They might be able to help out one of their constituents.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I looked over the flight data for TK17 from the last 2 weeks and the closest it came to the US other than on descent into YYZ was approx Saguenay QC, ~175km from the border. And that was on a very deviated (to the south) routing compared to the GC distance. It crossed the Atlantic from the bay of Biscay. Most flights come in over northern Labrador. This seems excessive.

Comment: @Richard At the time I wrote my comment, there were two flights from Detroit to Europe (one to Munich; I think the other was to Amsterdam). Both had passed within a couple of kilometres of YYZ and then gone on to fly over Maine -- the [great circle routes from Detroit to Munich and Amsterdam](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=IST-YYZ;MUC-DTW) are both north of the YYZ-IST great circle until one is over the far east of Canada. I'm not sure what you're describing as excessive.

Comment: @ikegami Or [Halifax (YHZ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halifax_Stanfield_International_Airport) or [St. John's (YYT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._John%27s_International_Airport).

Comment: I'd like to suggest flying via Halifax but (though you might want to double-check) I suspect that it too is affected by the US no-fly list even though it's miles from the US border.

Comment: I asked [this related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133306/will-a-usa-no-fly-blacklist-prevent-canada-passengers-from-flying-domestically) to ask if you'd be able to continue your air journey *after* you make it to Gander, St. Johns or Halifax.

Comment: @ChrisW Yeah, I suggested Halifax and St Johns *only as alternatives*, but it turns out, if you book a domestic flight from Gander to Toronto or Montreal, they make you change at Halifax or St Johns.  It's true internationally too, flights from LHR or CDG-Gander make you change in Halifax or St Johns.  Although FWIW, Gander is a "hidden city"; extending the trip to Gander lowers the price.

Comment: @Harper Even if you take the bus to Halifax I suspect they might still use the US no-fly list on international flights terminating at Halifax.

Comment: @Harper +ChrisW Gander might be a temp solution that i really haven't considered thanks .

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thats actually what i did and they have been swift and helpful until now. thanks for suggestion

Comment: I have the same situation for years and no one helped out. After years of living here and work hard establishing our lives, we are in a big prison named Canada.
This is the reality my friend!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Originating in Halifax will not help as getting there from Toronto or Montreal will take you over northern Maine, i.e. over US territory.  Best option is via Montreal where (in summer at least)  almost all TATl flights never go over the US unless they go  to southern Europe.  Alternative is to use Calgary as a gateway, where there is 0 risk of going over US.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have yet to be on an eastbound transoceanic flight that did anything like the great circle route--they always go way south because of the wind situation.

Answer (score 129):

As you've discovered, US regulations apply not just to flights to or from the US, but also to flights that pass over the US.  Before such flights the airline will send APIS data (basically the details of the everyone on the flight) to the US Government, who can flag certain passengers as appears to have happened here.

Your only real recourse is to apply to the US Department of Homeland Security [Traveler Redress Inquiry Program](https://www.dhs.gov/dhs-trip) (TRIP).  This will trigger the DHS to investigate you specifically, and if they determine that you should not have been blocked from boarding (which could be as simply as them confusing you with someone else, poor data on their behalf, etc) then they will remedy this.

As a part of the TRIP process you will be given a "Redress number" which can be used on future bookings, and will allow the government to match up your TRIP application and determination with your flight.

Of course, it's very possible that the DHS will determine that you are on a blacklist, and that fact is justified, in which case there's really nothing more that can be done.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90579/discussion-on-answer-by-doc-i-am-on-the-us-no-fly-list-what-can-i-do-in-order-t).

Answer (score 36):

Unfortunately if you’re on a USA no fly list, **and** you’re not a citizen or permanent resident, you have very little recourse.

[Who Can Challenge the No-Fly List?](https://foreignpolicy.com/2018/05/01/who-can-challenge-the-no-fly-list/)

> In 2014, the American Civil Liberties Union obtained a federal court
>   ruling that U.S. citizens and lawful permanent residents were entitled
>   to know if they were on the list and potentially know what got them
>   there. Baz’s case, if successful, could extend that right to foreign
>   nationals.

Even if this case is successful, in your case you’re not someone who has been coming to the U.S. and has a long history of coming to the United States and has significant ties to the United States.

Comment: He could try the diplomatic channels by contacting his representative, or his Foreign Affairs department. Changes are slim though. About his problems in Canada, I am pretty sure he has a case against the Canadian authorities giving him long interrogations.

Comment: Thank you for all the input. I will be studying it now.

Comment: It would be funny to become a US citizen for the sole purpose of fighting your inclusion in the no-fly list. Would be a good topic for a comedy movie.

Comment: @Tom After seventeen years I [became a US citizen for the sole reason of traveling to UK without a visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for), after being denied a renewal.

Comment: Canadian usage of the US no-fly list causing harm to a Canadian may be possible to challenge in Canadian courts.  It might only fix "in airports by our own Canadian customs agents every single time"

Comment: @Yakk but it seems the problem is not Canadian use of the no-fly list, but the fact that many flights to or from Canadian airports require clearance to enter US airspace.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the Canadian embassy if you haven't already; if they can't help contact as many Canadian media as you can to raise awareness.  If you make a big enough stink they might help you.

Comment: They're not allowed on flights passing through US airspace - what's the Canadian embassy going to do about that?

Comment: I was directed to the appropriate governing Ministry. I will be pursing a resolution in the justification Via the Minister of Public Safety and Emergency Preparedness. Public safety Canada's Passenger Protect Inquiries Office (PPIO) provides advice and assistance to individuals who have experienced travel delays or difficulties related to aviation security lists.

Comment: The asker is a Canadian citizen. Which Canadian embassy are you suggesting they go to?

Comment: Unfortunately, you will likely find that the Canadian government relies heavily on the US no-fly list for a variety of profiling tasks. I very much doubt you will be able to skip the interrogations while you are still on the no-fly list. Also unfortunately, the current political climate and acute fear of terrorist and dislike of immigrants in the US makes redressing the situation much harder than it should be. Go through the American DHS and get yourself removed from their list if you can. Pretty sure this is the only way out...

Comment: @ArasCelik:  Please keep us posted on your progress.  After things are resolved, you can post an answer to your own question detailing what you did and how it worked out;  posting such information would be very useful to people in similar situations in the future.