# Will a USA no-fly blacklist prevent Canada passengers from flying domestically?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, borders

Related to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133147/canadian-citizen-on-us-no-fly-list-what-can-i-do-in-order-to-be-allowed-on-fli), apparently someone who is on a  USA no-fly list will not be allowed on **international** flights between other countries, if they have a chance of overflying or diverting to the US.  And it's understandable that airlines would check this as part of the immigration prescreening, since they have to do that anyway.

So several people suggested he fly from Europe to Canadian airports nowhere near the US, such as Gander, Halifax or St. John's.  That's great, but if you flew internationally into St. John's, the only sane way to travel onward is flight.

They don't do immigration prescreening on domestic flights. So would he still get flagged/blocked if he attempted a St. John's-Toronto or Halifax-Vancouver domestic flight?

Comment: There's a perfectly good train service from Halifax, calling at Montreal and Toronto.

Comment: The Toronto - Vancouver train takes four days.

Comment: In theory domestic Mexican flights could also be affected.

Comment: @DJClayworth The train from Halifax to Montreal takes about 24hrs. This is comparable to the driving distance but of course without the need to operate a motor vehicle the whole time :)

Comment: Note that a lot of Canadian domestic flights routinely overfly the U.S., most notably flights to/from Victoria, BC and flights into or out of the southern Ontario airports (Windsor, London, Hamilton, Toronto Pearson, Toronto Billy Bishop).  My flights from Regina to Toronto have flown as far south as over Green Bay, Wisconsin.

Comment: @chx And is something like C$3,000

Comment: @AzorAhai: Maybe depends on dates?  I just randomly looked up fares for the Sep 15 train; coach starts at $444 and sleeper fares are available from $1320.

Comment: @nate I could be recalling a two way fare

Comment: @AzorAhai having done the Vancouver to Toronto train journey in the top class, I can say it's worth every penny

Answer (score 7):

The answer is **no**, they would not be prevented from boarding a domestic flight. Canada's compliance with the TSA no-fly list started in 2011 with the passage of [Bill C-42](http://www.parl.ca/DocumentViewer/en/40-3/bill/C-42/royal-assent/page-30):

> Despite section 5 of the Personal Information Protection and Electronic Documents Act, to the extent that that section relates to obligations set out in Schedule 1 to that Act relating to the disclosure of information, and despite subsection 7(3) of that Act, **an operator of an aircraft departing from Canada that is due to land in a foreign state or fly over the United States and land outside Canada or of a Canadian aircraft departing from any place outside Canada that is due to land in a foreign state or fly over the United States** may, in accordance with the regulations, provide to a competent authority in that foreign state any information that is in the operator’s control relating to persons on board or expected to be on board the aircraft and that is required by the laws of the foreign state.

As we can see, only flights that depart or land outside of Canada are permitted to transmit APIS data to foreign officials and thus domestic flights are exempted. This interpretation is confirmed in the [legislative summary](https://lop.parl.ca/staticfiles/PublicWebsite/Home/ResearchPublications/LegislativeSummaries/PDF/40-3/c42-e.pdf) published by the Library of Parliament.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for running the bounty!  Also I think people in both Oxford and Chicago would agree, Canadian lawmakers could stand to use more commas :)