# Return to UK after having been refused entry years ago

Tags: uk, us-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry

So I was turned around from Heathrow airport in 2012 after customs stopped me and asked me what my plans were in London. I told them I was there to Dj...they then asked me if I was making any money. Not thinking anything of it I said I was and they asked how much. I told them $500...which wasn’t even true, I didn’t know if I was making any money or not. They then brought me to a holding room and asked me a bunch of questions and eventually they told me they didn’t believe me about not making money and sent me back to US.

Now fast forward 7 years my wife has bought us tickets to Heathrow for May. And now I am of course kind of freaking out because I have a stamp in my passport with an X over it.

Comment: What are your plans for the new trip? Are you a US citizen?

Comment: @henning vacation I am a us citizen. redherring what important documents? Do you think it would be ok without the visa and just pass with going as a tourist. Do you think they have me as a red flag? Thanks guys

Comment: I am not working at all, so why get the visa? Then have to explain why I do have a visa but to not work, you know? @redherring

Comment: @RaulPeña the purpose of applying for a visa is to basically sort your situation out - you were refused entry at the boarder in 2012, which is a black mark on your slate right now.  Only a successful entry or a successful visa application can remove that mark, so the question is whether you want to take the risk of travelling and being refused in May, or applying for a visa now and either be denied prior to travelling (at which point you can make other arrangements) or receive a visa which pretty much guarantees you entry when you present yourself at Heathrow.  The visa removes all doubt.

Comment: @Raul Peña The UK visa site https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism advises that as a US citizen you are eligible for visa-free entry but you may want to apply for a visa if you’ve previously been denied entry.

Comment: "I told them $500... eventually they told me they didn’t believe me about not making money" -- confusing. Did you tell them you'd be paid, or not? Did they send you back because they *did* believe you that you'd be making $500, or because they *didn't* believe you? It may make a difference whether the refusal was because you openly admitted something that made you ineligible, or because they thought you were deceptive.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for

Comment: @nanoman I get the impression that he told them he'd be paid and then tried to change his story.

Comment: @nanoman OP said it in a "running his mouth" sort of way, then tried to walk it back when he realized it made them frown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you everyone for all of the advice. I have decided to apply for a visa before heading out. I have an interview next week with UK visas and immigration.

Comment: What documents should I bring to my visa immigration interview? Bank statements marriage license etc? Thanks guys

Comment: @nanoman yes basically that’s what the case was. Being arrogant and naive. I applied online and now I have an interview next Friday.

Comment: Also if I am denied the visa application for whatever reason can I still show up to borders and plead my case with all of the proper documentations? Or if my visa hasn’t been approved yet before my trip will they see that I have a pending application?

Comment: Of course you *can*, but the immigration officers at the border has access to the information that your visa was rejected and why, so it's probably pointless

Answer (score 55):

Seven years ago you presented yourself at Heathrow as a US citizen and requested visa-free entry. Visa-free entry requires that you don't work, and that you do not apply for public funds. It also assumes that you will leave the UK within a reasonable period of time.

When questioned you announced your intention to work, and to earn money for it. Since this breaches the terms under which you would be admitted, you were denied entry.

Now, you're proposing to arrive at Heathrow and request entry a second time. Immigration computers have long memories and the border guard will know about a prior refusal. You will be questioned, perhaps at length. If you try and lie your way through you'll be denied a second time and you can forget visiting the UK for a long time.

You need to persuade the border guards that you will comply with the terms of visa-free entry, and with your previous refusal you can expect them to be skeptical about any claims you make.

You should document links to the US, focussing on anything that requires your presence there, to show that you have reason to leave the UK. You should document your income and savings to show that you can afford your visit. And you need a convincing explanation for why things are different this time and you aren't going to work.

You could just show up at Heathrow with all this documentation and try to persuade the border guards to let you in. It can be done, but you could be detained for some hours.

Or, you can apply for a Visitor's visa before you leave the US. If you get the visa, great! If you don't, you avoid the questions and pain at Heathrow. And if the UK border guards ask why you have a visa, just explain about the prior refusal and that you wanted to be sure you'd be allowed to enter.

Comment: OP also prevaricated on whether he was working at all, and when he sniffed that working might be a matter of concern to authorities, tried to walk it back.  Immigration calls that "deception" and casts shade on any other claim he might make.

Comment: +1 apply for a visitor visa, if that gets denied you saved yourself a trip.

Comment: @RaulPeña How did it go ultimately?