# Express Lanes at UK Immigration

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports

Just last week the UK implemented allowing citizens  of certain countries including the Five Eyes signatories to use the Express Lanes at Immigration checkpoints.

[Government expands use of ePassport gates to 7 more countries](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/government-expands-use-of-epassport-gates-to-7-more-countries)

> From today (Monday 20 May), visitors from Australia, Canada, Japan,
>   New Zealand, Singapore, South Korea and the United States will be able
>   to use ePassport gates at ports across the UK and juxtaposed controls
>   in a move designed to speed up border controls for low-risk countries.

Are people who previously had issues with UK immigration eligible to do so?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for/89879#89879

Answer (score 3):

The given link implies yes, since any traveler who has had issues in the past and are **rejected** at the gate:

- will be sent to a manned passport check to have their identity and passport checked

There is no **explicit** statement stating that certain categories of persons should not use these gates.

Comment: It's reasonable to expect that anyone with a stop indicator on their passport who tries to use the gates will be rejected at the gate. The UK will not suddenly be uninterested in such people.