# Incoming debit transactions in statements

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

In my bank statement there are a few incoming transactions such as 800 or 1000 or 2500 apart from my monthly salary. These amounts are mine which my friends have paid back to me as I have paid for various things (such as we were traveling together, or having dinner together, the bill is paid by me through my credit card, and their share is paid back to me from their bank account online).

How can I justify this scenario to visa officers while submitting the application for a UK visitor visa?

Comment: The natural thing to do would be to tell them exactly what you just told us surely?

Comment: By telling the truth. It is not difficult. That said if they form a significant portion of your overall balance, it is not a good sign.

Comment: Thanka for your reply sir.. My debit balance transactions for entire 6 months statements is coming around total of 12 to 14 thousand Saudi riyaal and my monthly salary is around 9 thousand saudi riyaals which is getting deposited every month. So how can i explain them these incoming miscellaneous transactions. Do i need to write a letter and explain them??

Comment: "Do i need to write a letter and explain them?": The more detail you can give, the better.  Consider that 14,000 SAR is about GBP 3,000, which is not insignificant.  It's also equal to over 1/4 of your salary of SAR 54,000 over six months.  I think it is unlikely to be overlooked.

Comment: Your monthly salary is 9,000 so for 6 months it is 54,000. So the **total** miscellaneous deposits of 14,000 which is about 25% of your salary for the period in my opinion is not what I would consider classic funds parking. **I think you are fine**. Personally I would not write a letter for such an amount. In my case they got me for deposits which were two times my monthly salary. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for/89879#89879

Comment: I'll add that the round-number amounts, constituting a significant proportion of the deposits into your account, may raise concerns that the deposits are not actually payments for shared expenses, as shared expenses rarely are round figures (e.g., 1000 SR) but instead are non-round amounts (e.g., 897.50 SR).

Comment: Thanks for your response guys... I just have one more question.. My salary is 9000 SAR.. and the same will be deposited every month in my bank.. How much i need to spead or withdraw monthly and hoe much do i need to save for better flow of bank transactions.. Which have good impact on visa officer to avoid rejection of my application..

Comment: [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) explains in detail about what a good bank statement would look like.

Answer (score 1):

You explain it by telling the truth, you paid (specified items) in cash for someone and they paid you by bank.

The amount of money is significant but not the amount people would usually use for funds parking. When well explained it should not be a problem.

There is no 'wanted' or 'needed' amount for your bank and savings account, it is showing you can afford this travel and have a stable job to come home to.