# Do UK Immigration Officers record video when interviewing arrivers?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

I have always been curious about this process. Do officers record video in the event that they or other immigration officials need to scrutinise the details from interviews, whether on the part of the officer OR the passenger, later on?

Comment: I was detained by UK immigration three times with one detention lasting over eight hours and interviewed in detail twice for about an hour. The interview was **not** recorded although the questions and answer were copied down almost verbatim and signed by both of us. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for. However note that the common arrival hall is on video surveillance. Of course they can’t decipher what the 1000 people in the hall are saying.

Comment: Common video hall as a whole, but not individual booths where arrivers initially report to officers on their way through?

Answer (score 13):

There is no evidence to suggest that immigration interviews are recorded. If people were being recorded it would be on the privacy notice:

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/779876/borders-immigration-citizenship-system-privacy-notice.pdf

Answer (score 11):

For immigration purposes,Border Force Officers do not tape or video record interviews at the desk or in their interview rooms. The interviews are supposed to be hand-written verbatim (both questions and answers). If an interpreter is used (speaker phone) the notes will be in English.

CCTV in ports/airports in the UK are the port/airport operator's property but are made available to Border Force & Police to (for example) track an individual back to a flight if they arrive at the desk with no passport and claim asylum. The airline can then be identified and  and the passenger's point of departure prior to the UK can be ascertained.

Comment: Since I’ve never seen an officer write down transcripts of interviews at the desk, I assume you’re referring to interview rooms used when it is determined that further questioning is needed, as user 56513 referred to.

Comment: @Matthis, thanks for clarifying. "Trigger notes" may be made at the desk (not a full interview)  but interview rooms when more detailed questioning is considered necessary.

Comment: "trigger notes" indicating reasons that arriving passenger is being detained for questioning, or recording minor details about their personal information/answers to questions at the desk?

Comment: @Matthis. Noting key salient points if arriving passenger's explanations are complex. Possibly to consider further questioning or possibly to confirm 'no further action' (landed)with superior, if it's not something that that Officer has encountered before.