# UK immigration Stamps: Are there Different types?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

In other years, I have received multiple stamps on my visa indicating "leave to enter" terms et cetera, but most recently, my visa was just stamped once with the entry date and no other stamps. What's with this? Have the UK changed the entry rules recently?

Comment: Hi Matthis! Could you edit the question to make the title more unique? It's hard to differentiate it from other questions about UK immigration stamps right now.

Comment: No the rules have not changed. There have **always** been different types of UK entry stamps. Example https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-denied-visa-apply-for which have one regular one regular box + another box with annotation, and some without the extra box with annotation. If it’s only the standard one box, it’s for standard **six** months. Those with annotation may have specified reduced durations or other restrictions.

Comment: @user56513 the standard six-month leave to enter has traditionally been indicated with two stamps, the "extra box" in this case saying "leave to enter for six months: employment and recourse to public funds prohibited."

Comment: @ user 56513 standard one box allows entry for 6 months - if they are being given a reduced duration, the passenger will always be made aware?

Comment: Yes they will **always** make you aware if giving you less than six months. Either verbally or by stamp, usually both. You have asked two questions about UK visas/immigration. Are you facing some problem?

Comment: @phoog That cannot be correct, at least in my case. I am looking at eight standard six-month leave to enter entry stamps in my passport and four have only one box, the remaining four have two boxes with one the standard box and the other different for each.

Comment: @ user 56513 "Are you facing some problem?" - Based on what I've read here, no. My visa came in the form of an entry clearance sticker in my passport, which was then stamped just once upon arrival. So I infer that I have 6 months, since I cannot remember any verbal statement that I have less time.

Comment: Some UK visa vignettes are explained here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/854601/visa-vignettes-used-for-certain-categories-of-UK-visas-Dec-19.pdf

Comment: @user56513 perhaps we're not using "box" to refer to the same thing.  In the question that you linked above, there are two images, both with an additional box (although one is not fully enclosed and has no manual annotation, bearing only a standard text).  I've never seen a UK entry stamp without one sort of additional box or the other.  But it is possible to find them online, as I have just discovered.  Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @phoog I have retired from posting answers. Kindly do the honors when you have time.

Comment: @user56513 that is a shame.  Matthis, can you confirm the type and validity of your entry clearance sticker?

Comment: @phoog interestingly it’s an Entry Clearance Visit sticker valid for six months. I say interestingly because last year, the same application for the same kind of visa gave me a green sticker that said “visa”.

Answer (score 4):

The most common stamp for visa-free visitors is code 5n, issued when a stay of up to 6 months (the maximum) is granted and there are no particular suspicions about the entrant. The former landing cards would then be discarded.

[image]

Then there's code 3, issued when, for example, there are suspicions about the entrant (insufficient to refuse entry), when a visa national transits landside at an airport, or for visa-free short-term students. Known as a *recorded landing*, it used to involve retaining the landing card and writing the landing card number on a rectangular stamp. I honestly don't know how it's done now.

[image]

The rectangular stamp is also issued for non-recorded landings when a maximum stay of less than 6 months is granted.

[image]

Finally, visa holders and UK residents will normally receive an open date stamp, i.e. only the square stamp with the date and port of entry.