# UK visa refused for insufficient funds

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

My visa was refused for insufficient funds. There is no time to go through the whole visa application and it is expensive.

Would I be allowed to enter, or do I need to consult an attorney?

My airfare and accommodation have been paid, and I have $3000 as spending money.
The airfare and accommodation are $2000 and $3000 is just spending money. This combined is $5000AU, or 3000 pounds; that is 200 pounds a day. Is this acceptable for travelling for 15 days in the UK from Australia?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're saying that you applied for a UK visa even though you do not need one? Why did you do that?

Comment: @ZachLipton it's fine for somebody to do that.  They want an entry clearance to avoid wasted airfares and the distress of a port removal.  It's fine

Comment: This is a very plain (e) refusal. But I don't get it. If you do not have the money to travel, how is it that you are going anyway?  That part doesn't make sense, would you edit your question an explain?

Comment: I have paid most of my accommodation in advance in air BnB, you have to pay first, that is $1000AU. the air fare and comprehensive travel insurance was $1000 for return ticket, and $200 or insurance, so that is $2200 Au.  paid out already...I have $3000 cash for a 15 day stay; that is for food..entertainment 15 days...how much do I have to spend, 200 pounds a day for a healthy bank is 3000pounds or $5000au.  take out the amount I have paid and it is added to $5000au or 3000 pounds 200 pounds a day...?

Comment: this is the second part to my first question, trying to edit now the question to make clearer,sorry,  but the extra money to pay for a new visa application and a rush order before I go next week, was not referring to my money for my stay in uk in question...

Comment: I have money for my stay..than you so much for helping me, yes I wanted a visa to be sure of my stay in UK

Comment: @GayotFow it really reads like ECO missed to put it some point(s) in the decision, and glad to see that I'm not the only one who can't make heads or tail of it. Although after re-reading, I think it's simply poorly typed and if you will change it to read "however you have *not* demonstrated your income or any available funding" it kinda makes sense.

Comment: I suspect the issue is not so much the money you have on hand, but rather **provenance of funds**. How were you able to save that $5,200 on $20,000 salary which is from probably irregular freelance work? You will need to supply a lot of bank statements showing your transactions over a period of about six months which can show the source and pattern of inflows and outflows into your account. You must be able to show this without [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications).

Comment: @JonathanReez yes, that's fine, please mark it.

Comment: I told them I was on a pension ,,is this enough to show how I saved?