# Schengen Tourist Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds

We (my wife and parents-in-law) are taking a 14-day vacation in the Schengen countries. Right now, I am in the process of preparing all the required documents for the visa application (Schengen Tourist for 14 Days). In the checklist, one section states:

> Applicants having no financial means of support must produce a letter from their sponsor confirming the commitment of full financial support for the applicant for all his/her expenses during the stay in France and the Schengen zone. A photocopy of the sponsor passport and sponsor last three months personal bank statements must be provided."

This is applies to my wife and mother-in-law who are housewives and not working. Questions are:

1. Can I (IT professional) support my wife ?
2. Can my father-in-law (retired) support my mother-in-law?

Note: Both of us can provide all the necessary support letters and documentation (passport copies, bank statements with sufficient funds etc.).

Comment: Yes and Yes if you have the income generating assets and/or jobs and pensions (in your fathers case) to support them and the trip. Note that bank statements are not only about sufficient funds, but the ACTIVITY in the statement. Don't get caught in [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications) issues etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I (IT professional) support my wife ?

**Yes**, absolutely.

> Can my father-in-law (retired) support my mother-in-law?

**Yes**!

There are several people on here who have had third parties provide the funding for their visas and have obtained the visas. The closest third party one could have is an immediate family member, typically a spouse.

The yeses are conditional on you/father having the income generating assets and/or jobs and pensions (in your fathers case) to support them and the trip. Note that bank statements are not only about sufficient funds, but the ACTIVITY in the statement. Don't get caught in [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications) issues and ensure that the provenance of the funds in your account are clear etc.

Comment: Any sources to back those yeses?

Comment: @chx The statement by the consulate itself is confirmation that a person can have a sponsor. Additionally I have provided sponsorship/financial support for my spouse for visa on several occasions.