# UK visit visa refused twice in a row

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

What if visit visa refused twice once in 2012 and latest on 12/5/17? Though i was granted visa in 2007 and i stayed more than intended days but within visa  limit .Is there any  chance they would allow me third time if I kill the queries. 
How can I assure ECO that I am in Government sector job since 1998 with good position  , a home and a family with 3 children. I provided all relevant docus each time and they raised new question like they don't want me enter uk though sponsor is my brother who is British citizen with excellent job position in one of the reknow institution
Refusal letter attached for kind advice [image: first page]

[image: last page]

Comment: Your refusal notice has not been uploaded, did you forget? Anyway, they have been refusing if your history shows abuse and it's likely you have a credibility hit. We have lots of stuff about prior abuse in our archives here, please check it out and upload your refusals, thanks

Comment: New to app . Pardon if find difficulty to read it

Comment: Dear Paul i waited for 5 years since last refusal. Provided all relevant docus like I had bank deposit of 1.1 million on particular date which I got by selling my vehicle and to buy new one but ECO took it another way though I endorsed sale deed but he didn't interlink bank deposit and sale deed both happened on same date.

Comment: 2. When you are Goverment employee you get leave on production of Visa. ECO asked why I didn't get leave prior to issuance of Visa and he also accepted that you are eligible for leave

Comment: Read this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications. Unfortunately selling your possessions before a trip is taken as meaning you don't plan to return soon. Plus your income is relatively on the low side. Try to visit a different affluent country and then in some years apply to UK again.

Comment: your kind advice is appreciated

Comment: @user61594 this is a very standard type of refusal, we have dozens of these, please read the linked question and you'll have all you need. They got you this time on funds parking, but you have a serious credibility hit from previous abuse. Be careful and read the links!

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie nice call and nice spotting, indeed funds parking spelled doom, thanks