# Application for UK Visa rejected. How do I make my second application stronger?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

[image]

I am a recent college graduate planning on a graduation trip to London and Scotland.

My tourist visa application was refused because of lack of evidence of my employment and evidence that I will be coming back to my country. Also because of a sudden uplift in my funds, they don’t believe my bank statement is a true reflection of my financial circumstance and that the funds in my bank statement might not be available for my exclusive use.

I believe I have sent an employment letter but no pay slip for the past 6 months. I’ve been working part time at my workplace for the past year and a half. Because I work part time, I do not have a fixed schedule. I work whenever I am free and sometimes it’s only once a month or even not at all because of school commitments so my income might not have been reflected in my 6-month bank statement. I had my finals mid this year as well as my graduation in September so I was only able to cover about 2 shifts at work over the last 6 months and wasn’t able to provide a pay slip.

However I was working more frequently from May to November 2016 and saved my income as well as pocket money from my parents, which amounted to about $4000. I transferred most of my income and deposited my cash allowances to someone else’s account for safekeeping as it was my plan to go on a graduation trip at the end of 2017 and didn’t want to risk spending the money. I only asked to transfer the money back to me before submitting my documents for my visa application. This explains the sudden uplift in my funds. I do see how it looks dodgy and would like to know how I can explain this to them? Would it help if I could provide payslips from 2016 that shows I was indeed getting an income that could amount to $4000?

My father has also offered to do a partial sponsorship of $3000 for my UK trip. He initially intended for the $3000 to be a surprise graduation gift, to be given before I leave for London. However since my visa rejection, he offered to write a letter declaring his role in sponsoring my funds. What should the letter contain and should there be any other documents to support this? Would this help in convincing them that I can in fact, support myself for the 17 days in UK?

As for evidence of return to my country, I am also on a Tuition Grant Scheme with the Government of Singapore which requires me to work in Singapore for 3 years upon graduation, which happened on the 3rd of September 2017. Failure to do so would make me liable for liquidated damages. I did not add this info/document as I wasn’t sure it was necessary. Would this additional info help my case? I also have a return ticket, fully paid!

Please advice on how I can make my application stronger. I am supposed to leave for London on November 30 2017 and have less than 2 weeks to get a visa. I will be travelling with a Friend who has also recently graduated.

Comment: This appears to be a typical case of what is known as "funds parking" on this site.  Please see [What is 'funds parking' in the context of UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications) and [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! It was really helpful! But do you reckon that my Tuition Grant scheme with the Government of Singapore constitutes as a good reason for me not to overstay in the UK? Because I just graduated and am required to work in Singapore for 3 years or I will have to pay really big damages for breaking the bond. Is that a strong enough case to prove that my family has given me money for my trip purely as a graduation gift and isn’t depending on me to find work in the UK?

Comment: Funds parking is only one of the issues with this application. I wish the question were reopened so that the other issues could be answered.

Comment: I’m not sure how to use this site I’m so sorry. How do I reopen the question?

Comment: I’ve asked a few more questions on a separate post however I’m not sure how to link it. If you could please click on my profile and read the new post, I’d appreciate it so much. Thank you for replying!!