# I am unemployed and my Schengen visa got refused despite having all documents and proof. What should I do?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals

[image]I applied for a Schengen Visa for Slovenia on the 23rd of April. After a few days, my visa got refused stating, "you have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence..". This was despite having sufficient proof of funds in my sponsor's bank account. I have submitted all documents accordingly but they still refused my visa for the above reason which I think is totally false. My trip is being sponsored by my dad and his funds are enough to support the travel. I found through various sources that this might have been due to the fact that I'm unemployed, and that they are suspicious that I will overstay my visa and become a potential illegal immigrant. Whereas I've no plans on doing so nor any interest. I am planning to ask for a review of my application, but I am confused what should I do so that they take up my case for review again and approve the visa this time. Is there any chance my visa will be approved? Please help me regarding what I should do so that my visa gets approved. I am planning to visit Slovenia this July 16th, for a music festival where I'll be meeting my girlfriend for the first time ever. I am 25 and have enough funds in my sponsor's account to support this trip. I am extremely sad and anxious. Please, please help!

Edit: Picture attached!

Edit 2: Since my visa was denied due to lack of funds("insufficient means of subsistence") will the embassy re-consider it's decision if my sponsor puts in more or adequate amount of money before I make an appeal or re-apply? Or would that make me look suspicious. How do I fix this issue of less funds if I have to appeal or re-apply without making them think I have malicious intents.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the refusal letter with your personal details blanked out? Likely reason, on the information so far, is that the money is in his account and not in yours so it looks like it's not really yours to spend.

Comment: @Tulip Das Was that the only refusal reason given? How long were you planning to stay and what purpose did you state for your visit? What is your nationality?

Comment: Make alternative plans, like her coming to meet you. Or find some employment and become financially secure.

Comment: @user16259 Schengen refusals are not accompanied by letters. They come in the form of a checklist. The full text of item three is "you have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of 
the intended stay or for the return to the country of origin or residence, or for the 
transit to a third country into which you are certain to be admitted, or you are not in a 
position to acquire such means lawfully."

Comment: @user16259 as far as I know after asking some travel agents, if the trip is sponsored, it doesn't matter if the traveller's account has less money at the time of visa application.

Comment: @Traveller Yes that was the only refusal given. I was planning to stay for a fortnight(15 days), from 16th to 31st July. My purpose was to visit MetalDays(metal music concert) in Tolmin, Slovenia.

Comment: A "girlfriend you've never met" will never be understood by non-millennials, and Immigration thinks they're saving you from a scam, *and they see a lot of this, so they'd know*.  I'd tend to agree.  How much did they ask about "her"?  Are you really attached to going to Slovenia specifically?  There are 194 other nice countries, and many have music festivals.  It erodes the "tourism" claim to be trying really hard to enter one specific country.

Comment: @Harper I get it that it does look suspicious. But we are only trying for Slovenia cause the festival there is of two weeks in length(if you include pre-arrival). So we wanted to spend as much time as we want together.

Comment: Also if I apply for Slovenia next year for same festival with proper documentation and proof that I will return to my home country, will they accept then? Or will they bar me again since I have had one refusal

Comment: What would help most is if you found another heavy metal festival this year outside Schengen and went to that instead, and returned on time and did not overstay or seek employ.

Comment: Since my visa was denied due to lack of funds("insufficient means of subsistence") will the embassy re-consider it's decision if my sponsor puts in more or adequate amount of money before I make an appeal or re-apply? Or would that make me look suspicious. How do I fix this issue of less funds if I have to appeal or re-apply without making them think I have malicious intents. I say this because in a fresh re-application or review you generally fix your inadequacies of your first application. But then as people have said here before it might look suspicious. I'm so confused and torn.

Comment: Certainly seems like: "unemployed" + "meeting girlfriend" = "what incentive do you have to return home?"  Getting your father to park extra money in your account probably won't help and could make your application look even worse.

Comment: Also, I kinda feel the embassy just gave the "insufficient funds" as reason for refusal just as a pretext for the fact that I am unemployed. Cause when you look at it, this reason can't be fixed in the second application if you reapply. Since inadequacies demand amendments in 2nd application, this reason can't be done anything much about. Cause if I wanna put sufficient amount in my A/c I'd be victim of suspicion and funds parking. So the embassy might have thought why not just put this reason so that he gets cornered out. I understand this is due to my unemployed status though.

Answer (score 9):

The Schengen countries try to welcome genuine tourists and refuse entry to illegal immigrants. They cannot *know* what a person will do in the future, so they must go by the documents.

- You will need both money for the trip and for your stay in the Schengen area. I think Slovenia wants to see €70/day, which adds up to quite a sum over a few days. Do you have that money, in addition to your ticket?
- If your girlfriend plans to give you housing and food then you'll need less money, but explaining this would make it even harder for you to convince the visa authorities that you will leave again.
- Even if your father pays for your trip, you will have to document *your* financial circumstances as well as his. Did you?

Being unemployed does not lead to an automatic refusal. But it means that the rest of your application has to look good.

My *guess* is that the initial decision is correct according to the documents, and that an appeal will not help. In the EU it is entirely normal that official forms contain information how to appeal them, that does not mean an appeal is likely to work.

---

**Follow-Up:** When someone else pays for your trip, your account still has to show a stable lifestyle with regular income exceeding regular expenses. Even if that income is money from your parents (which is not uncommon for young people). If the money for the trip is a *gift* to you, you should be able to use it as you please, so it helps if you have it.

Comment: @Yes, my trip is being sponsored by my dad. So yeah he has enough funds to support the trip, along with the ticket which is already booked.

- My gf is also travelling to Slovenia, she is from Macedonia. So no chances of housing and fooding from her there.

- Yes, I did document both of our statements. But as far as I know, if my trip is sponsored, I don't really need to have enough funds in my account at the time of visa application? That's what I came to know from a few reliable sources.

Comment: @TulipDas, I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm from India as well (got several schengen visas over the years). You haven't mentioned your age. If for e.g. you're 25 and unemployed, the Embassy might feel there is a chance of you staying back in the Schengen area, since you have no job to come back to.

Comment: Yes I am 24. But it is such a stupid reason. One can stay back despite any document he presents. Ugh too irritating!

Comment: @Tulip Das From the refusal response, you didn’t show you have a reason to return; it’s not impossible that the sponsorship actually harmed your application since without ties to your home country if you decided to overstay your father could perhaps continue to support you. It’s also possible the visit premise was not very credible.

Comment: @Traveller to be honest, they didn't ask me for any such documents which prove the rootedness to my country. All they asked for were duly submitted. Also, does this mean, I still have to submit a proof of reason to return even if I hold a job or am pursuing some course in an University?

Comment: @Tulip Das Read the guidance on Supporting Documents Required for Short Term Visas. It refers to ‘information enabling an assessment of the applicant's intention to leave the territory of the EU Member States before the expiry of the visa applied for. http://www.mzz.gov.si/en/entry_and_residence/for_visa_applicants/

Comment: I concur with what `Traveller' posted. Look at this from the Embassy's point of view. Most illegal migrants are young people unemployed or underemployed in their home country and who do not realistically have the means to holiday abroad. Visa agents can and do produce letters from Schengen residents offering to sponsor visa applicants, so Embassies would be sceptical about this.

Comment: So if re-apply with a updated bank AC statement with sufficient funds and also attach a 'proof of integration into the country of residence: family ties; professional status', such as birth certificate(?), will my visa be approved? Just tell me what should I do so that my visa gets approved if I apply for a second time. 

I'm getting enrolled in a college this month as well. So will they accept proof as student(enrollment slip & NOC from college) for more documentation proof? Or are they going to object since it wasn't there in the first place? 

Just tell me what should I do for approval?

Comment: The enrollment in college would count in your favour because it's a reason to return. A birth certificate doesn't prove integration or ties.

Comment: @Tulip Das There’s no guarantee you will be granted a visit visa. If you reapply so soon after a refusal, ‘fixing’ the deficiencies of your first application could well give the impression that you’ve only done it to get the visa eg a sudden college enrolment when you didn’t have that the first time, money that is miraculously in your account looks like a ‘funds parking’ strategy, as discussed here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications

Comment: @Traveller That's what I am wary of. Also, the student enrolment was pre-planned and I had to enroll, even if I didn't apply for visa. It's just that the enrolment timing & visa refusal is clashing, so it makes them look like I’ve only done it to get the visa, which is not the case. And the money is from my sponsor, agreed that it's an all of a sudden a huge amount in my account, but then it's sponsor's money. Few travel agents have told me that if my trip is sponsored my account need not reflect sufficient amount, since I'm sponsored. If I reapply it'll be in June, since I leave in July.

Comment: @Traveller But it looks like whatever I do I can't get a visa no matter what. I think there is no use re-applying again, since everything I would do to fix my deficiencies of first application will be looked upon with a shadow of suspicion. I have no goddamn intent to become an illegal immigrant. So would you reckon it's best to just not apply? Will I be banned from Schengen Area if I get denied again? And is there still ANY hope or ANY way I could turn this in for me?