# Does a second Schengen visa refusal through appeal hamper my future travels?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals

Here's [my first refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114347/i-am-unemployed-and-my-schengen-visa-got-refused-despite-having-all-documents-an), which I posted here and you can take a look if you want to get a clear view of my case.

So I appealed for the first refusal and the consulate replied, telling me to deposit 153 EUR to their bank. I can do that, but I am in a fix as I know that my visa still stands a chance to get refused. And I know that it will affect my future travels with two serial refusals. I am confused what I should do. Should I go for it and pay the consular fee so that they review my case again and stand a chance to getting my visa refused again? Or should I play safe and re-apply next year? Please do let me know about the intricacies of appeal and how does or will it affect my passport. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
The Slovenian Embassy called me and said they'll review my case once I pay the consular tax fee of 153 EUR for review. And then I'll have to send them the payment slip on email as proof. And he said after that, we're gonna ask for your passport and "*we'll put the visa on it*". I asked and clarified and he kept saying the same thing. Also clarified if I need to appear for an interview, and he said not needed.
I am kinda happy but since this whole thing has been going against me I am taking this with a pinch of salt. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 4):

You got a lot of feedback on your previous question, none of which indicated that an appeal of your first refusal would be successful - although you disagree with it, the decision looks correct based on your circumstances. If you appeal, the review would be of the original application and its associated evidence submitted at the time, they will not take anything new into account so you can pretty much expect the same outcome, although I don’t think it would count as a second refusal (others may disagree, I can’t find a source right now). You’d be better to wait before reapplying, improving your circumstances meanwhile.