# My UK visit visa has been refused twice. Can I re-apply as the refusal was unsatisfactory?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, uk-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

[image]
[image]
[image]

The first refusal (green) was my mistake, as I thought I could show my credit card as well and the employment leave of absence was missing.

The second refusal (black), they think that I have unknown credit in my account, whereas the truth is that it was my annual leave payout and I have shown and given the payslip as well. Also, my friend deposited approximately 5,000 AUD, as she wants to sponsor me. I have already repaid her, as it was an issue in the second refusal. Can I re-apply or am I out of options? I wanted to visit my friend. I live  in Australia as a temporary graduate, and I have my sister, brother in law and our home and property.

Comment: You can apply again and then you will more than likely be promptly refused. It's your call. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications . The refusal was unsatisfactory to YOU, and that is normal because you're upset and disappointed. However it is not unsatisfactory to them, and is actually very correct and satisfactory under their guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but they have refused my under 2 ground, i can accept that there was fund parking as i was unaware that i cant get help but the second reason was unsatisfactory as that $3311 was my annual leave with my salary . Can i do something about this ??

Answer (score 3):

They refused you because of doubts about the legitimacy of the unusual credits to your account (referred to on TSE as ‘funds parking’. There are lots of similar questions, there’s nothing to stop you reapplying but with 2 refusals already you need to take great care to address all the shortcomings and provide reliable evidence [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) Your chances of success at the moment are probably pretty low

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know that there was unusual transaction ,but i want to  clarify that $3311 was my annual leave pay out with my salary and have given payslip as evidence .Do i have any chance re applying ??

Comment: @Pritam Shrestha If I’ve understood correctly you are employed by Ferndale Gardens but the $3311 came from Aspic Holdings. The connection isn’t obvious. You also say you’re living (and working) in Australia as a temporary graduate, your immigration status and ties that would compel you to return are also unclear. A 3rd application will almost certainly be refused unless it is fully coherent and all facts presented are supported by reliable evidence. Best advice is to accept the decision for now and work on improving your background & financial circumstances.