# PLAB 2 visit visa refusal with refugee status

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, refugees

[image: Refusal letter page 1]

[image: Refusal letter page 2]

I have been refused a UK visit visa to take the PLAB 2 exam for the third time and it's so frustrating. Let me briefly explain my case for better understanding.

I'm an Afghan refugee residing in Pakistan since 1992 with my family and one of my brothers is in the UK as a British citizen. I completed all my education in Pakistan and now working in a local hospital as a permanent employee. I cleared my IELTS and PLAB 1 in November 2017. Since then I applied for a UK visit visa for 3 times and was refused. I took help from a visa consultant for the third attempt but without success.

I have a refugee card issued by UNHCR and the Pakistani government. I have a visit visa to travel between Afghanistan and Pakistan.

In my third refusal letter, the ECO stated that my residence card is due to expire in November 2018 and the 3,500$ deposited once as savings from my 6-month salary is above my income (approximately 500 GBP more). The ECO also said that my family's whereabouts are not available although * provided evidence of my 3 of my 7 siblings' educational documents to show they study and work.

Please help and guide me on what I should do. I intend to go to the Maldives and work there for at least 4 months, open a new bank account and reapply for a visa from India. Will this help clarify my situation and change my circumstances?

Comment: As a refugee with only a temporary permission to reside in the place where you live it will be very tough to qualify for a visit visa. Is there a way you could become a permanent resident of Pakistan? I doubt that going to the Maldives for 4 months will improve you chances of getting a UK visa, as it will only prove that you have fewer ties to Pakistan.

Comment: where did that lump sum come from? any irregular deposit (other than salary) should be documented - e.g. if you sold your car or recieved some one-off bonus or something like that

Comment: There in only one reason to take the PLAB, that is to work in a UK NHS hospital. Were the other applications (and refusals) for the same, to sit the exam? With three refusals, re-locating is not likely to improve your chances of being granted a visa. Have you consulted an immigration solicitor in the UK?

Answer (score 3):

To be approved for a visa, you need to resolve the issues that are shown in the refusal letter.

These are:

- A large deposit was made into your bank account which was not explained. This *by itself* is [sufficient to cause your application to be refused](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/62411/3221). All deposits into your bank account need to have evidence of their sources included with your supporting documents.
- Your residence permit expires in a few months. Pakistan might not extend the stay of Afghan refugees again, and the ECO is concerned that you might be looking for a third country to immigrate to. This also is sufficient by itself for a visa refusal. To overcome this you will need to change something about your "personal and economic circumstances in Pakistan" - whether this is making more money, or migrating to a third country, or returning to Afghanistan.
- The ECO did not consider the documents you submitted regarding your family members sufficient to prove that they are currently living in Pakistan. You should obtain documentation which proves they are currently living and/or working in Pakistan, such as apartment leases, payslips, etc.