# UK short-term tourist visa for my husband and me

Tags: uk, tourist-visas

We are planning to travel to London next month from India. A short 2-week trip to see London and nearby places. I have some queries regarding our tourist visa:

1. As husband and wife, can we show the same set of documents, especially financial documents?
2. Both of us are working and have our savings in joint accounts. Now my salary is less than my investment (as my husband invests in our joint account). As visa officers try to connect the salary to the investment, will this create problems?
3. Do we need to show the originals of our property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> As husband and wife, can we show the same set of documents, especially financial documents?

Yes, This is clearly stated in the *Supporting Documents Guide Section 4*.

> If you are applying as a family/group you do not need to provide multiple copies of the same documents

The important this is that you provide the GWF of your spouse in the remarks section in both the applications.

> Both of us are working and have our savings in joint accounts. Now my salary is less than my investment (as my husband invests in our joint account). As visa officers try to connect the salary to the investment, will this create problems?

I don't think that should be an issue as long as there is no fund parking ([What is 'funds parking' in the context of UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications)).  You can always explain this in the *Extra Information* section to be more clear.

> Do we need to show the originals of our property?

Yes, The UK supporting documents guide states:

> All documents must be originals and not photocopies.

and this applies to all the documents including the property papers if you are planning to attach them with your application.