# Will UK officials check my bank account after my Visa Application?

Tags: visas, uk, turkey

I am applying for a visa from Uk, Turkey and Georgia Embassy. Please, I need to know if these embassies will call my bank to confirm my statement and how much i have in my account, after submitting my application, I don't spend from my account while waiting for my application to be confirmed .

Comment: Just apply for the British visa. For Turkey then you can get an eVisa in 3 minutes and to Georgia you can travel visa free then.

Comment: I don't entirely know the answer to your question in the title, but even if they do they certainly won't expect you to have not spent anything since the beginning of the application process. You can continue using your bank account as usual. Nobody's going to deny you a visa because you bought groceries while they were processing the application.

Comment: Nobody knows. I know in my home country of Ghana [and countries with high incident of fraud and fake documents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNg-H9yV0f0),  they sometimes do random spot checking.

Comment: They are not absurd. They know people get deposits and withdrawals from their bank account every day. You are worrying about nothing.

Answer (score 7):

**If** they try to confirm your balance, the key thing is to avoid the appearance of what we call [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications). Some applicants believe that they only need a certain amount of money on their statement, rather than a regular pattern of deposits and withdrawals. So they borrow a large sum of money, put it into their account, and get a statement with a high balance. If there is the suspicion that you did this, the visa will be denied.

So it would be a good idea to avoid large and unusual deposits before the application and large and unusual withdrawals after the application. Just go on using the account as usual. **A steady pattern is good.** If you cannot avoid large transaction, explain and document them.

Comment: The other side of this is that you do not need to avoid your normal, routine, withdrawals. Many perfectly fine bank accounts tend to have a lower balance just before a payday than just after.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, yes, keep the routine. Changing it *either way* looks strange, and strange is bad.