# How do I explain employment contract changes in my UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-employment

How do I explain my salary: my previous salary changed from basic fixed plus incentives fixed, to basic fixed plus commission unfixed (which can be higher or lower each month). For the first month, I was paid in all cash. Now, after talking to HR and pressuring them, I get the basic amount in my bank account but commission can't be deposited as it's variable and so they give that to me in cash. What should I do?

I can, of course, get a salary letter stating this about the cash commission slips. Previously, I was refused for not explaining cash deposits and insufficient funds. How do I explain this change in my new application?

Comment: Which country are you in? In most places where salaries are usually paid by bank transfer, suddenly getting part of it in cash is often a sign of tax fraud.

Comment: You explain it by explaining it clearly in the comments section of the application, like you are doing here. The ECO's reviewing applications knows the customs that pertain in the country they are responsible for. They are not working blindly.

Comment: It's just that sometimes it feels like they don't even see the documents we attached. Just my thoughts

Comment: Another thing I wanted to clear is if I should deposit the Comission I get as Cash every month in my bank or not?

Comment: Do they give you payslips with the cash indicating the amount and any tax withheld?

Answer (score 5):

Break it down and explain it like you have done here. The main thing is to be completely clear and transparent about the funds in your account and where they come from to prevent any doubt. They will read the documentation, and you mentioned getting a letter confirming your payments from your employer, I agree this would only be beneficial to include as it will help to confirm the legitimacy of these funds.

If you choose to deposit the commission money each month, make sure to explain this and highlight those transactions to avoid any accusations of funds parking (this is where you put extra money into your account to make it seem like you have more money, read more about this [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications)).