# Do bank statements in French need to be translated for a UK visa application?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I hope my concern will make a sense here.

I am a Congolese student in South Africa. I am planning to visit the UK for my holidays. My father (a company owner since before 2013) in Congo is supporting my studies and trip but his documents are in French. I am hesitant whether I should submit a bank statement in French at the UK visa centre here in South Africa. Should I have it translated into English?

What should I do? There is no way to be sure from the UK Home Office information.

Comment: I can’t find a source so this is just my opinion, but I doubt you are expected to translate bank statements. UKVI rules require original documents, even without a translation I’d say bank statements are usually sufficiently generic so as to be self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks alot. Because I have used previously my uncle's statement for UK Visa application which is in English as I stay with him but I got refused as reason: I did not demonstrate ties between me and him. So I want now to use my Father details

Comment: The [guidance is clear on that point](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf): required supporting documents must be in English or Welsh. As your father's financial information/bank statements are among those, they must be translated (and certified by a qualified translator/translation company). After a refusal, you would want to tick off all the boxes.

Comment: @Traveler my mother in law one had a visa application denied, in part because she did not provide a translation of her bank statements.

Comment: @Giorgio that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Phoog Thank you, I had not imagined that it is even possible to get a translation of a bank statement :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [UKVI Visitor: supporting documents guide](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) is clear on that point:

> If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office.

Among other documents, financial information is required:

> Financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available. These must
>   clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as:
>
> - bank statements
> - building society book
> - proof of earnings such as a letter from employer confirming employment details (start date of employment, salary, role, company contact details)
> - where a third party (who is either in the UK or who will be legally in the UK at the time of your visit) is providing financial support to you e.g. a business, a friend or a relative, documents to show they have sufficient resources to support you in addition to themselves and any dependant family should be provided.

As your father supports you, his financial information/bank statements must be translated (and certified by a qualified translator/translation company). For the latter, the [UK lists of translaters and interpreters abroad](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/lists-of-translators-and-interpreters) may help. Note it is not the sole source of such information, but just a place to start.

You may also want to show that you have access to his funds, and that they are set aside for your specific use. At this point, don't be tempted to have him transfer monies to your bank.

These comprehensive Q&As should help, as you prepare your application:

[Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab0)

[UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

[What is 'funds parking' in the context of UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications)

Comment: "You may also want to show that you have access to his funds" how can i show it ???

Comment: @GuyMuanda, that's another question, you'll need to ask a new question for an answer