# uk visa refusal ( add new documents will it help)

Tags: visa-refusals, paperwork, applications

I applied for UK standard visit visa (6 months) for tourism and i got refused for some reason can be seen in the picture , can any one explain to me why i got refused and if the new documents i will provide will help ?

new provided documents 
1-i bought a land and i will provide documents proving that.
2-i will add my father as a sponsor and will get a 6 month bank account statement for him and documents showing he owns his own pharmacy .

before applying for the first time i added 2000 pounds to my bank account , got my bank account statement then withdraw the money to convert it to pounds , should i add a letter about that?

there is about 3000 pound in my bank account and it can be noticed they are my pay check and no large deposits , i will added father bank account with( 2000 pounds to 3000 pounds) as a sponsor , will that be sufficient knowing i am staying for a week in uk?

Documents I applyed at first application 
1-6 months bank statements
2- papers from my company proving I still work there 
3-parentes house documents 
4-document showing I am still with family not married or anything
5-fathe pharmacy papers 
That's all I believe

[image: refusal letter for uk visa]

Comment: It **may** help however it looks like you lack knowledge about how to prep War a solid application. Either spend a lot of time reading about uk Visa applications from here or get an immigration attorney. I expect you need several hours or days reading answers here to become somewhat knowledgeable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105

Comment: They say "you have not submitted any documentation." Does that mean you didn't attach any financial statements to your first application?

Comment: I did submit a 6 months bank account statment at my first application , this time I am not gonna deposit any money only my pay check , adding the old man as sponsor next to myself , I just don't understand the one about my personal and family circumstances .

Comment: @user89744 Read the first SE answer cited in Honorary World Citizen's comment; it discusses the issue behind "personal and family circumstances." Adding your father as sponsor will not address this issue.

Comment: i had a call with my company and asked them to feel a new form which includes ( job title , monthly salary , start date of employment and company details ) .

Comment: when it comes to family circumstances i am not sure what to do here since i am not married nor have kids and still living with my parents .

added documents for the lands i own which is 2.

and for the last part i will show bank statement for my self and father with the registration documents for his pharmacy.

i am gonna have about 5000 pound in both accounts combined , trip total expenses about 2700 pound max . 

can anybody tell me if this is enough?