# Should I deposit money back into my account when waiting for a visa

Tags: uk, proof-provenance-of-funds, business-travel

I submitted my papers including a copy of my bank statement to the UK embassy and everything was going great, after a day or two I had to withdraw some money from my main bank account (where I get my salary payments) to lend to someone. Now I got the money back, should I deposit it back into my bank account or would it look bad?

I am going to UK for business related matters, the company I am working at is my sponsor and they provided me with all the necessary documents. The original balance was 2370jod, I lent 500jod.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand this question at all. What is it that you are asking?

Comment: Should I put the money back to my bank account or I shouldn't since it's not my normal income and I am afraid I will ge a refusal because of that ?

Comment: @user89744 If it’s your money, and you can prove where it originally came from, why wouldn’t you put it back into your account? As it stands, withdrawing an unusual amount soon after submitting a visa application might look like funds parking to an ECO.

Comment: Why are people rushing to close the question? The question is very clear and not a duplicate. Obviously the OP is a non native speaker however the question is quite clear.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen The question is certainly clear to me. But I do think that anything we could say in an answer is already covered in our canonical funds parking question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 'funds parking' in the context of UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications)

Comment: Have you already submitted bank statements as part of your application? Did the withdrawal happen after the statements were submitted? Was the original deposit of 'money that did not originate from my normal source of income' shown on the bank statements you submitted?

Comment: Guys thanks for the edit but its  kinda changed my question , I submitted a bank statement with 2370jod for the bank account I get my salary into and after 2 days I had to withdraw 500 jod to give to someone and now since I got them back should I deposit them back or not ?

Answer (score 1):

> I submitted a bank statement with 2370jod for the bank account I get my salary into and after 2 days I had to withdraw 500 jod to give to someone and now since I got them back should I deposit them back or not ?

You should [make sure your bank statements help you demonstrate that you have a stable lifestyle at home](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105), and that you have enough funds to support yourself for the entire duration of your trip. Do not try to play the system and do not overthink this. Just be truthful when applying and make sure you meet the requirements to be eligible for a visa.

Having said this, I think it is more likely that removing 500 after submitting the statement will be construed as [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications), than putting the same amount back once the money returns to you. Hence, I would put them back and I would not think about it too much. In addition, it is your money and you can prove its origin so i do not see anything fishy here.

Do note that at the end of the day the decision lies within the Immigration Officer's hands and solely they can decide whether or not you are eligible for the visa.