# UK Visit visa wrongly refused

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

A brother applied for a UK visit visa, he is self employed (a CEO/Business owner) and applied for a Visit Visa using only  his company bank statement to apply.

The commission refused the visa thinking that he used his personal bank statement, so they indicated that his salary didn't reflect in his personal bank statement and the monthly inflows were more than his stated monthly salary.
  Clearly who ever worked on the documents assumed it was his personal bank statement so passed judgements indicating that his personal bank statement indicated undisclosed sources of funds hence the refusal.

If only they had taken time to read through they would have realized it was his company statement and not a personal statement.

He was informed that he cannot appeal 
What can he do about this error ?[image]

Comment: Kwame, your case is not as bad as I originally thought, i.e it is not a+c+e. The refusal is only under **e**. That is quite mild. They got your brother under what we call **funds parking** over here. Basically unexplained deposits not matching ones salary. They got me in 2015 on that even after I had been issued two successive five year multiple visas. This is easier to address than a+c+e. He can reapply with a cover letter explaining things very clearly what bank statement he is using. A business owner can use his company statement however he needs to explain things clearly in a cover letter.

Comment: Before he reapplies read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications and other highly upvoted questions on uk visas, particularly answers by [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow). Make sure in the part of the application that asks about your monthly expenditures, the figure you quote makes sense w.r.t. the salary and how much he plans to spend on vacation in the UK.

Comment: There is no appeal, they did away with appeals of visitor visas years ago. Now the way to appeal is through a fresh application which covers the bases of the reasons you were previously refused. Make sure the subsequent application is well put together. You do not want to get a second successive denial in a short period of time, that will become problematic. Also very important, read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab about bank statements.

Comment: @Kwame Agyeman As Honorary World Citizen states, a business owner can use his business bank statements to support his application. He should also submit his personal bank statements, which should show receipt of drawings from the business (ie his salary) and his personal expenditure and ongoing financial commitments. To substantiate funds in his business income account he should think about submitting tax returns, trading (profit & loss) accounts, and invoices to substantiate deposits.