# I need advice for my reapplication for UK Visit Visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

[image]
I’m an international college student in Hamburg, Germany. I have applied for Visitor Visa in 2017 and this is the refuse letter from my last application. There are a few changes in my application that I want to ask for advice.

- In the last application I have stated that I have no friend in the UK. But this time my boyfriend will write me an invitation letter and I will be staying at his place during the trip. Do I have to clarify why did I say that i have no friend in the UK in the last application?
- I’m a non-working fulltime student and receive regular allowance only from my family. What documents do I have to provide beside my bank statement? Plus I have a cash deposit of 6000 Euro in my bank sent from my family 3 months ago. Do I have to prove its origin, if yes what documents do I need? The reason for the large amount of money is because my family only send me twice a year.
- First thing is that, I have a penalty fare ticket last year in Germany for the amount of 60Euro for not having the right ticket for the different zone in Berlin and I have transfered the fee right after. Second is when I flew back to Germany from Vietnam, I have a fine for bringing meat to Germany for 46 Euro and also have to pay tax not fine for bringing cigarettes. I have paid everything right after. So my question is do have to disclose them in the section: “Warning, caution, reprimand, or other penalty” in my application form?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also relevant: [What is "funds parking" in the context of UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/62411/11491)

Answer (score 1):

Q1 Your boyfriend’s invitation: you don’t have to explain that you didn’t have a UK boyfriend last time you applied (assuming you didn’t have one) but you do have to demonstrate that there is a genuine personal relationship eg how/when you met, evidence of ongoing communication, visits by him to see you

Q2 You’ll have to provide evidence of where the money came from and that it was legally obtained, typically this is a bank statement from the person who gave you the money and possibly their pay slips or other evidence of the source of the money

Q3 Yes, you do.

Source: See Immigration Rules App V https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Comment: I agree except with respect to the cigarettes, if that was simply payment of the regular customs duty (perhaps deferred) and not a fine.

Comment: Penalty fare tickets are administrative penalties and in my opinion don't have to be declared since they don't form part of a criminal record. Custom penalties are similarly administrative and there is no criminal liability.